# python concatenating a list without restarting

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I'm trying to concatenate new rows of data into an old main dataframe. However, whenever I try to run my for loop. My old main dataframe restarts that's because of the exfive = pd.DataFrame() however without it. The Dataframe wouldn't have even been created. Also, if I hash it. The output gives me double the concatenated rows. So how do I go about being able to concatenate new rows of data without restarting or doubling my main?

```
nums_list = [2000,5500]
nums_list_two = [8000, 9000]

for num_list, num_list_two in zip(nums_list, nums_list_two):
    ex5 = pd.DataFrame({'colone':nums_list,'coltwo':nums_list_two})
    ex6 = pd.DataFrame({'colones':nums_list_two,'coltwos':nums_list})
    exs_list = [ex5, ex6]
        
    ex_mod = []
    for ex_list in exs_list:
        ex_list = ex_list.T
        ex_mod.append(ex_list)
            
    ex5 = ex_mod[0]
    ex6 = ex_mod[1]
    exfive = pd.DataFrame()
    exfive = pd.concat([exfive, ex5], ignore_index = False, axis = 0)
    del ex5
```

desired output:

```
          0      1
colone  1000    4500
coltwo  7000    8000
colone  2000    5500
coltwo  6000    9000
```

What I get when I have the pd.Dataframe not hashed:

```
          0      1
colone  2000    5500
coltwo  6000    9000
```

What I get when I have the pd.Dataframe hashed:

```
          0      1
colone  1000    4500
coltwo  7000    8000
colone  2000    5500
coltwo  6000    9000
colone  2000    5500
coltwo  6000    9000
```

I've tried this:

```
nums_list = [2000,5500]
nums_list_two = [8000, 9000]
exfive = pd.DataFrame()

for num_list, num_list_two in zip(nums_list, nums_list_two):
    ex5 = pd.DataFrame({'colone':nums_list,'coltwo':nums_list_two})
    ex6 = pd.DataFrame({'colones':nums_list_two,'coltwos':nums_list})
    exs_list = [ex5, ex6]

    ex_mod = []
    for ex_list in exs_list:
        ex_list = ex_list.T
        ex_mod.append(ex_list)

    ex5 = ex_mod[0]
    ex6 = ex_mod[1]
    exfive = exfive.append(ex5)
```

I don't get the desired outcome:

```
          0       1
colone  1000    4500
coltwo  7000    8000
colone  1000    4500
coltwo  7000    8000
```

I've also put the concat outside the for loop below it.

```
finalexfive = pd.concat(exfive, ignore_index = False, axis = 0)
```

But I get the outcome:

```
TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"
```

Comment: Put `exfive = pd.DataFrame()` just *before* you begin the loop?

Comment: You should avoid using pd.concat() within a loop, because it's inefficient. Here's an example of how to avoid this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70975988/530160

Comment: ShadowRanger - I did that but it just doubles the concatenated rows. Any other ideas?

Nick ODell I tried their solutions but when I append ex5 into exfive and then tried to concatenate it outside the for loop. I was getting:
TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"
Not too mention when checking exfive it was doubling the appended rows.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer

Say you have `df1` and you create `df2` with the new list, provided they have the same column names, try doing `df = pd.DataFrame(df1, df2)`

Do tell if this worked.

Comment: I don't know if I understood you well but I tried something like:
finalexfive = pd.DataFrame(ex5, exfive)
Outside of the for loop. I got the error:
ValueError: Index data must be 1-dimensional

Could you clarify exactly where I would put that?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns = ["a", "b"])
print(df)
to_append = [5, 6]
a_series = pd.Series(to_append, index = df.columns)
df = df.append(a_series, ignore_index=True)
```

This might also work. Basically you are trying to add new rows to the existing dataframe.