# Pandas DataFrame to List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
customer    item1      item2    item3
1           apple      milk     tomato
2           water      orange   potato
3           juice      mango    chips
```

which I want to translate it to list of dictionaries per row

```
rows = [
    {
        'customer': 1,
        'item1': 'apple',
        'item2': 'milk',
        'item3': 'tomato'
    }, {
        'customer': 2,
        'item1':
        'water',
        'item2': 'orange',
        'item3': 'potato'
    }, {
        'customer': 3,
        'item1': 'juice',
        'item2': 'mango',
        'item3': 'chips'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 553, accepted):

Use [`df.to_dict('records')`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_dict) -- gives the output without having to transpose externally.

```
In [2]: df.to_dict('records')
Out[2]:
[{'customer': 1L, 'item1': 'apple', 'item2': 'milk', 'item3': 'tomato'},
 {'customer': 2L, 'item1': 'water', 'item2': 'orange', 'item3': 'potato'},
 {'customer': 3L, 'item1': 'juice', 'item2': 'mango', 'item3': 'chips'}]
```

Comment: How would I change it to include the index value into each entry of the resulting list?

Comment: @GabrielL.Oliveira you can do df.reset_index().to_dict('records')

Comment: Is the order of the columns reserved in each case i.e. is the nth entry in the resulting list always also the nth column?

Comment: @Cleb are ```i.e. is the nth entry in the resulting list always also the nth column?``` nth column or nth row?

Comment: Is `records` some kind of magic column name?  Are there other magic columns?

Comment: @StephenBoesch See the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html   'Records' is a str arg to orientation of the result.

Comment: @GabrielL.Oliveira You can also do df.todict('index') to get a nested {index -> {col->value}} set of dicts

Comment: @Cain How do you personally go about finding that documention?  I use `PyCharm` that is close to worthless in that regard (though invaluable as a debugger and in other IDE functions)

Comment: I agree that it's a bit "magical" in a less than intuitive way... but it works!

Answer (score 330):

Use `df.T.to_dict().values()`, like below:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
   customer  item1   item2   item3
0         1  apple    milk  tomato
1         2  water  orange  potato
2         3  juice   mango   chips

In [2]: df.T.to_dict().values()
Out[2]:
[{'customer': 1.0, 'item1': 'apple', 'item2': 'milk', 'item3': 'tomato'},
 {'customer': 2.0, 'item1': 'water', 'item2': 'orange', 'item3': 'potato'},
 {'customer': 3.0, 'item1': 'juice', 'item2': 'mango', 'item3': 'chips'}]
```

Comment: What would be the solution in the case of a dataframe containing for each Customer many rows?

Comment: When I use `df.T.to_dict().values()`, I loose the sort order also

Comment: When opening a csv file to list of dicts, I'm getting twice the speed with `unicodecsv.DictReader`

Comment: Check the answer below, of @mirosval and @Zero. Best way is to use `df.to_dict('records')`

Answer (score 25):

As an extension to [John Galt's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2137255/john-galt) answer -

For the following DataFrame,

```
   customer  item1   item2   item3
0         1  apple    milk  tomato
1         2  water  orange  potato
2         3  juice   mango   chips
```

If you want to get a list of dictionaries including the index values, you can do something like,

```
df.to_dict('index')
```

Which outputs a dictionary of dictionaries where keys of the parent dictionary are index values. In this particular case,

```
{0: {'customer': 1, 'item1': 'apple', 'item2': 'milk', 'item3': 'tomato'},
 1: {'customer': 2, 'item1': 'water', 'item2': 'orange', 'item3': 'potato'},
 2: {'customer': 3, 'item1': 'juice', 'item2': 'mango', 'item3': 'chips'}}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are interested in only selecting one column this will work.

```
df[["item1"]].to_dict("records")
```

The below will **NOT** work and produces a TypeError: unsupported type: . I believe this is because it is trying to convert a series to a dict and not a Data Frame to a dict.

```
df["item1"].to_dict("records")
```

I had a requirement to only select one column and convert it to a list of dicts with the column name as the key and was stuck on this for a bit so figured I'd share.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
my_records =  df.to_dict(orient='records')

print(my_records)

[{'customer': 1, 'item1': 'apple', 'item2': 'milk', 'item3': 'tomato'},
 {'customer': 2, 'item1': 'water', 'item2': 'orange', 'item3': 'potato'},
 {'customer': 3, 'item1': 'juice', 'item2': 'mango', 'item3': 'chips'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can iterate over rows:

```
rows = []
for index, row in df[['customer', 'item1', 'item2', 'item3']].iterrows():
    rows.append({
            'customer': row['customer'],
            'item1': row['item1'],
            'item2': row['item2'],
            'item3': row['item3'],
            })
```