# convert Dataframe to list of dict too slow

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import time

data = []
for i in range(3000):
    data.append(['SH601318', 'abcdef', 0.0001215, 0.000215, 0.125, 0.243])
df = DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['symbol', 'name', 'total_ratio', 'outstanding_ratio', 'avg_total_ratio', 'avg_outstanding_ratio']

t = time.time()
result = [{
    'symbol': df.at[i, 'symbol'],
    'name': df.at[i, 'name'],
    'total_ratio': df.at[i, 'total_ratio'],
    'outstanding_ratio': df.at[i, 'outstanding_ratio'],
    'avg_total_ratio': df.at[i, 'avg_total_ratio'],
    'avg_outstanding_ratio': df.at[i, 'avg_outstanding_ratio'],
} for i in range(len(df))]
print '%.2f seconds' % (time.time() - t)
# 0.25 seconds

t = time.time()
result = [df.iloc[i].to_dict() for i in range(len(df))]
print '%.2f seconds' % (time.time() - t)
# 0.58 seconds
```

I tried 2 ways to convert DataFrame to list of dict. But both are very slow, 250 ms and 580 ms! That's far more than time I query from database.   I don't know why it takes so much time, after all, manipulating memory is quicker than disk. I expected this time is in 10 ms. Is there any way I can achieve it?

Comment: Why not `df.to_dict(orient='records')`?

Comment: I can only surmise that the extra time comes from the loop: the overhead of each iteration is the fact that you are creating a Series as well as the overhead of the `to_dict` method each iteration.

Comment: @JohnGalt I ignore your answer in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815129/pandas-dataframe-to-list-of-dictionaries-dics) by mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with parameter `orient='records'`:

```
print (df.to_dict(orient='records'))
```