# How to convert a pandas DataFrame to a list of dictionaries where NaN values are omitted?

Tags: python, pandas

This question is similar to [Pandas DataFrame to List of Dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815129/pandas-dataframe-to-list-of-dictionaries), except that the `DataFrame` is not 'full': there are some `nan` values in it. Suppose I generate a `DataFrame` from a list of dictionaries like so:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}, {'foo': 3}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

so that the resulting `df` looks like

```
   bar  foo
0  2.0    1
1  NaN    3
```

I would like a function which turns `df` back into the original `data` list of dictionaries. Unfortunately,

```
assert df.to_dict('records') == data
```

fails because the former is

```
[{'bar': 2.0, 'foo': 1.0}, {'bar': nan, 'foo': 3.0}]
```

with the additional `'bar': nan` key-value pair in the second item. How can I get back the original `data`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's another way of doing it:

```
df.T.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().to_dict()).tolist()
```

Output:

```
[{'bar': 2.0, 'foo': 1.0}, {'foo': 3.0}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the problem with some 'post-processing':

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}, {'foo': 3}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

result = df.to_dict('records')
result2 = [{k: v for k, v in row.items() if not pd.isnull(v)} for row in result]

assert result2 == data
```

More elegant solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

1st Option

```
df.apply(lambda x: [x.dropna().to_dict()], axis=1).sum()
Out[860]: [{'bar': 2.0, 'foo': 1.0}, {'foo': 3.0}]
```

2nd Option

```
df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: [x.reset_index(level=0,drop=True).to_dict()]).sum()
Out[867]: [{'bar': 2.0, 'foo': 1.0}, {'foo': 3.0}]
```