# What is the more efficient way to generate all combinations of dicts in a list

Tags: python

I want to generate all combinations of a list that have the format:

`[{"first": a, "second": b, "third": c, "fourth": d}, {"first": e, "second": f, "third": g, "fourth": h}, {"first": i, "second": j, "third": k, "fourth": l}]`

where a, b, c, e, f, g, h, i, j are float between 0.1 and 0.9
and d, h, l are integers between -20 and 20.

I am using for loops with `range()` but it takes too much time or cpu.

Comment: python collections.combinations can simplify your code but probably will not speed it up

Comment: Please tell why you want to do that. It will help solving your problem.

Comment: Basically brute forcing a function. Providing two outputs, the list on the question and another known output I need to find a known result.

Comment: How should your combinations look like?

Answer (score -1):

You could do it through pandas, where each of your keys is a column in the dataframe and you then get the list of dictionaries out of it [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815129/pandas-dataframe-to-list-of-dictionaries)