# How to convert dataframe to a list of dictionary

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a hive table like

```
col1 col2 
id1  value1
id2  value2
id2  value3
```

I would like to covert it into a list of dictionary like

```
[{"col1": "id1", "col2": "value1"}, {"col1": "id2", "col2": "value2"}, {"col1": "id2", "col2": "value3"}]
```

Can anyone suggest what is the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

[Source](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

Comment: Thank you. Yes this is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
df.to_dict('records')
```

as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815129/pandas-dataframe-to-list-of-dictionaries/29816143#29816143)

Comment: Thank you. Yes this is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

For pandas, using `df.to_dict('records')` is great, but if you'd like to see how we can convert it from a regular dictionary to your expected result:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'],
                   'col2': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']})

dct = df.to_dict() # Convert to regular dict
lst = [dict(zip(dct, values)) for values in zip(*[dct[k].values() for k in dct])]

print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[{'col1': 'id1', 'col2': 'value1'}, 
 {'col1': 'id2', 'col2': 'value2'}, 
 {'col1': 'id3', 'col2': 'value3'}]
```