# How can we assign dictionary titles to items in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, plotly, gantt-chart

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

[image]

```
df = df_gantt.values.tolist()
df
```

[image]

I'm trying to create a gantt chart out of that.  Here's my code.

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff 
df = df_gantt.values.tolist()
fig = ff.create_gantt(df) 
fig.show()
```

Here is the error that I get.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PlotlyError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-fdb705605b1c> in <module>
      2 df = df_gantt.values.tolist()
      3 
----> 4 fig = ff.create_gantt(df)
      5 fig.show()

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/plotly/figure_factory/_gantt.py in create_gantt(df, colors, index_col, show_colorbar, reverse_colors, title, bar_width, showgrid_x, showgrid_y, height, width, tasks, task_names, data, group_tasks, show_hover_fill)
    943     """
    944     # validate gantt input data
--> 945     chart = validate_gantt(df)
    946 
    947     if index_col:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/plotly/figure_factory/_gantt.py in validate_gantt(df)
     64         )
     65     if not isinstance(df[0], dict):
---> 66         raise exceptions.PlotlyError("Your list must only " "include dictionaries.")
     67     return df
     68 

PlotlyError: Your list must only include dictionaries.
```

What am I doing wrong?  I am trying to follow the example from here.

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff 
  
df = [dict(Task="A", Start='2020-01-01', Finish='2009-02-02'), 
      dict(Task="Job B", Start='2020-03-01', Finish='2020-11-11'), 
      dict(Task="Job C", Start='2020-08-06', Finish='2020-09-21')] 
  
fig = ff.create_gantt(df) 
fig.show()
```

[image]

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gantt-chart-in-plotly/

When I try to run this.

```
df_gantt = df_final[['submarket','inservice_activation','real_estate_completed']]
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
df = df_gantt.to_dict('records')
fig = ff.create_gantt(df) 
fig.show()
```

I get this error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-5cb656f7907a> in <module>
      4 import plotly.figure_factory as ff
      5 df = df_gantt.to_dict('records')
----> 6 fig = ff.create_gantt(df)
      7 fig.show()

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/plotly/figure_factory/_gantt.py in create_gantt(df, colors, index_col, show_colorbar, reverse_colors, title, bar_width, showgrid_x, showgrid_y, height, width, tasks, task_names, data, group_tasks, show_hover_fill)
    976                 "assigning colors to particular values in a dictioanry."
    977             )
--> 978         fig = gantt(
    979             chart,
    980             colors,

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/plotly/figure_factory/_gantt.py in gantt(chart, colors, title, bar_width, showgrid_x, showgrid_y, height, width, tasks, task_names, data, group_tasks, show_hover_fill, show_colorbar)
     96     for index in range(len(chart)):
     97         task = dict(
---> 98             x0=chart[index]["Start"],
     99             x1=chart[index]["Finish"],
    100             name=chart[index]["Task"],

KeyError: 'Start'
```

Comment: What does `df = df_gantt.values.tolist()` look like? Is it a list of dictionaries like in the example?

Comment: No, WBM, it looks like what I showed in the image, in the update to my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is associated with your naming conventions, you need to rename your columns to match the example:

```
df_gant.rename(columns = {"old name1": "Start"}, inplace=True)
df_gant.rename(columns = {"old name2": "Finish"}, inplace=True)
df_gant.rename(columns = {"old name3": "Task"}, inplace=True)
```

Next rather than converting your dataframe into a list of values, you need to change your dataframe into a list of dictionaries. Try this instead:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
df = df_gant.to_dict('records')
fig = ff.create_gantt(df) 
fig.show()
```

See further details about transforming dataframes into a list of dictionaries [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815129/pandas-dataframe-to-list-of-dictionaries)

Comment: Thanks, but when I try to run that I get a bunch of errors.  I just updated my original post, with the errors that I see now.

Comment: Did you check what the list of dictionaries looks like? Does it match the example? A Gant chart needs a "Start" and an "Finish" datetime variable. 

So you will need to rename your variables

Comment: It's a specific KeyError. See the update to my answer.

Comment: I added the closing '}'before the comma and it worked perfect.  Thanks a ton!!!!