# Converting from dataframe to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe :

```
name   type     price   score
Beer1   Lager    3.5     4.1
Beer2   Porte    2.9     2.8
Beer15  Lager    3.2     4.2
```

I would like it to convert it to this form below (because I use an algorithm that take as input this format :

```
[{'name': 'Beer1', 'type': 'Lager', 'price': 3.5, 'score': 4.1}, {'name': 'Beer2', 'type': 'Porte <...> t', 'price': 2.9, 'score': 2.8}, {'name': 'Beer15', 'type': 'Lager', 'price': 3.2, 'score': 4.2}]
```

Should I convert it to list? list of list or list of tuple?
when I check with this instruction:

```
?beers
```

> Type:        list String form: [{'name': 'Beer1', 'type': 'Lager',
> 'price': 3.5, 'score': 4.1}, {'name': 'Beer2', 'type': 'Porte <...>
> t', 'price': 2.9, 'score': 2.8}, {'name': 'Beer15', 'type': 'Lager',
> 'price': 3.2, 'score': 4.2}] Length:      15 Docstring:   Built-in
> mutable sequence.
>
> If no argument is given, the constructor creates a new empty list. The
> argument must be an iterable if specified.

Any idea please?

Thanks

Comment: `[df.to_dict()]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use df.to_dict('records')

Link to the stack that solved the problem: [Pandas DataFrame to List of Dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815129/pandas-dataframe-to-list-of-dictionaries)