# pythonic way to get a zero-record slice of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame, and I want to get a zero-record slice. That is, a dataframe with the same columns but zero rows. The reason I am doing this, is because i want to have an empty dataframe, to which i add rows from the original dataframe in a loop.

Currently if am using:

```
empty = df[0:0]
```

is this the pythonic way?

Comment: `pandas` provides tons of ways to avoid loops, are you sure you need one?

Answer (score 4):

Well, obvious way to make dataframe with known columns is to do

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B", "C"])
```

You'll get empty dataframe as desired. But adding rows one by one is NOT most efficient way of operations

UPDATE

There was a discussion quite some time ago, take a look at [add one row in a pandas.DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: so in my case you are suggesting: empty = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

Comment: @eyaler if you really need it to do row-by-row, then yes

Comment: Note that this is different from a zero record slice, since it will have all object dtypes!

Answer (score 1):

You can get a zero-record slice by indexing with something that returns no rows:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1,2], "y": [1.2, 3.4]})

# select rows using an empty index, so get no rows back
res = df.loc[pd.Index([]), :]
```

Here's the result:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [x]
Index: []
```

The accepted answer does not necessarily give back a zero-record slice of the original DataFrame. Its dtypes will all be object. This is not the case with the approach above!

We can check its dtypes to verify:

```py
res.dtypes
```

Gives:

```
x      int64
y    float64
dtype: object
```