# Append an empty row in dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to append an empty row at the end of dataframe but unable to do so, even trying to understand how pandas work with append function and still not getting it.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd

excel_names = ["ARMANI+EMPORIO+AR0143-book.xlsx"]
excels = [pd.ExcelFile(name) for name in excel_names]
frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0], header=None,index_col=None).dropna(how='all') for x in excels]
for f in frames:
    f.append(0, float('NaN'))
    f.append(2, float('NaN'))
```

There are two columns and random number of row.

with "print f" in for loop i Get this:

```
                             0                 1
0                   Brand Name    Emporio Armani
2                 Model number            AR0143
4                  Part Number            AR0143
6                   Item Shape       Rectangular
8   Dial Window Material Type           Mineral
10               Display Type          Analogue
12                 Clasp Type            Buckle
14               Case Material   Stainless steel
16              Case Diameter    31 millimetres
18               Band Material           Leather
20                 Band Length  Women's Standard
22                 Band Colour             Black
24                 Dial Colour             Black
26            Special Features       second-hand
28                    Movement            Quartz
```

Comment: Can you explain a code a little bit? Its hard to gauge what you are trying to append - row, column or data frame?

Comment: @user3667569 I have data in xlsx in multiple rows and 2 columns and I need to add an empty row at the end. The for loop was just something I was trying with no luck.

Comment: Per comment from @Wes McKinney on https://stackoverflow.com/q/10715965/2829764 this is inefficient so best avoided for some applications because it involves copying all the data.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Add a new pandas.Series using pandas.DataFrame.append().

If you wish to specify the name (AKA the "index") of the new row, use:

```
df.append(pandas.Series(name='NameOfNewRow'))
```

If you don't wish to name the new row, use:

```
df.append(pandas.Series(), ignore_index=True)
```

where `df` is your pandas.DataFrame.

Comment: This works also for a datetime-like index by passing a datetime object to the name argument; e.g. `df.append(pandas.Series(name=datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 1)))`. Combined with `df.sort_index()`, the new row gets placed in the right position.

Comment: This is pocketdora's answer + a simpler alternative. My edits to their answer were rejected. I think it is important to have a single, standard answer to this very basic question.

Answer (score 20):

You can add it by appending a Series to the dataframe as follows. I am assuming by blank you mean you want to add a row containing only "Nan".
You can first create a Series object with Nan. Make sure you specify the columns while defining 'Series' object in the -Index parameter.
The you can append it to the DF. Hope it helps!

```
from numpy import nan as Nan
import pandas as pd

>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
...                     'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
...                     'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
...                     'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
...                     index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

>>> s2 = pd.Series([Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan], index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
>>> result = df1.append(s2)
>>> result
     A    B    C    D
0   A0   B0   C0   D0
1   A1   B1   C1   D1
2   A2   B2   C2   D2
3   A3   B3   C3   D3
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: I don't get it what I need to do to add "nan" row.

Comment: How will I add my current xlsx data in DataFrame?

Comment: Just load your current data into your data frame. Then replace the index parameter in this line to suit your need:  s2 = pd.Series([Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan], index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']) .

Comment: I already tried that and am getting this error "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Series'"

Comment: Okay, successfully done it thanks, had to set this with append function: "ignore_index=True".

Comment: This answer is unnecessarily complicated. You don't need to pass in a list of NaNs, nor do you need to specify all of the indices. @pocketdora and srcerer's answer are much simpler and accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `df` is your dataframe,

```
df_prime = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame([[np.nan] * df.shape[1]], columns=df.columns)], ignore_index=True)
```

where `df_prime` equals `df` with an additional last row of NaN's.

Note that `pd.concat` is slow so if you need this functionality in a loop, it's best to avoid using it.
In that case, assuming your index is incremental, you can use

```
df.loc[df.iloc[-1].name + 1,:] = np.nan
```

Comment: Excellent, this is more useful and can be used in many cases, thx

Comment: This is the best solution because pandas doesn't throw out a warning

Answer (score 5):

You can add a new series, and name it at the same time. The name will be the index of the new row, and all the values will automatically be NaN.

```
df.append(pd.Series(name='Afterthought'))
```

Comment: If you don't wish to name the new series, use `df.append(pd.Series(), ignore_index=True)`

Answer (score 5):

**Append "empty" row to data frame and fill selected cells:**

Generate empty data frame (no rows just columns `a` and `b`):

```
import pandas as pd    
col_names =  ["a","b"]
df  = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_names)
```

Append empty row at the *end* of the data frame:

```
df = df.append(pd.Series(), ignore_index = True)
```

Now fill the empty cell at the end (`len(df)-1`) of the data frame in column `a`:

```
df.loc[[len(df)-1],'a'] = 123
```

**Result:**

```
     a    b
0  123  NaN
```

---

**And of course one can iterate over the rows and fill cells:**

```
col_names =  ["a","b"]
df  = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_names)
for x in range(0,5):
    df = df.append(pd.Series(), ignore_index = True)
    df.loc[[len(df)-1],'a'] = 123
```

**Result:**

```
     a    b
0  123  NaN
1  123  NaN
2  123  NaN
3  123  NaN
4  123  NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

The code below worked for me.

```
df.append(pd.Series([np.nan]), ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: it also creates a new column of NaN values.

Comment: Or `df.append(pd.DataFrame([np.nan],columns=['A']))`, where 'A' is the name of any column in the df. Pandas will automatically fill up NaN to empty columns.

Comment: df.append(pd.Series(), ignore_index = True)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your df.index is sorted you can use:

```
df.loc[df.index.max() + 1] = None
```

It handles well different indexes and column types.

[EDIT] it works with pd.DatetimeIndex if there is a constant frequency, otherwise we must specify the new index exactly e.g:

```
df.loc[df.index.max() + pd.Timedelta(milliseconds=1)] = None
```

long example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[pd.Timestamp(12432423), 23, 'text_field']], 
                    columns=["timestamp", "speed", "text"],
                    index=pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2111-11-11',freq='ms', periods=1))
df.info()
```

`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 1 entries, 2111-11-11 to 2111-11-11
Freq: L
Data columns (total 3 columns):
timestamp    1 non-null datetime64[ns]
speed        1 non-null int64
text         1 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 32.0+ bytes`

```
df.loc[df.index.max() + 1] = None
df.info()
```

`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 2 entries, 2111-11-11 00:00:00 to 2111-11-11 00:00:00.001000
Data columns (total 3 columns):
timestamp    1 non-null datetime64[ns]
speed        1 non-null float64
text         1 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 64.0+ bytes`

```
df.head()

                            timestamp                   speed      text
2111-11-11 00:00:00.000 1970-01-01 00:00:00.012432423   23.0    text_field
2111-11-11 00:00:00.001 NaT NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
your_dataframe.insert(loc=0, value=np.nan, column="")
```

where `loc` is your empty row index.

Answer (score 0):

[@Dave Reikher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54184203/10136118)'s answer is the best solution.

```
df.loc[df.iloc[-1].name + 1,:] = np.nan
```

Here's a similar answer without the `NumPy` library

```
df.loc[len(df.index)] = ['' for x in df.columns.values.tolist()]
```

- `len(df.index)` = number of rows. Always 1 more than index count.
- By using `df.loc[len(df.index)]` you are selecting the next index number (row) available.
- `df.iloc[-1].name + 1` equals `df.loc[len(df.index)]`
- Instead of using NumPy, you can also use a python comprehension
- Create a list from the column names: `df.columns.values.tolist()`
- Create a new list of empty strings '' based on the number of columns.
- `['' for x in df.columns.values.tolist()]`