# How to update the Index of df with a new Index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently having one df which has an incomplete Index. 
like this:

```
Idx  bar  baz  zoo
001   A    1    x
003   B    2    y
005   C    3    z
007   A    4    q
008   B    5    w
009   C    6    t
```

I have the complete `Index([001, 002, ...... 010])`. 
Would like to how to supplement the complete Index into the incomplete df.

```
Idx  bar  baz  zoo
001   A    1    x
002  nan  nan  nan
003   B    2    y
004  nan  nan  nan
005   C    3    z
006  nan  nan  nan
007   A    4    q
008   B    5    w
009   C    6    t 
010  nan  nan  nan
```

The `nan` can be "", the purpose is for me to identify which case I am currently missing.
It's the first time I ask question on stackover, apology for the poor formatting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append an empty row in dataframe using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39998262/append-an-empty-row-in-dataframe-using-pandas)

Comment: This method works, I need to use a for-loop though:

```
# setup a complete DF with complete index
for index in index_li:
    if index not in df.index:
         df= df.append(pd.Series(name=index))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this easily by using the pandas df reindex method..

[df.reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

all you have to do is supply a list to be used as the new index i.e.

```
full_index = ['001','002','003','004','005','006','007','008','009','010']
```

then pass this into the reindex method like this:

```
df = df.reindex(full_index)
```

the method will automatically put nan values into the rows with indices that were not in the original index...

e.g.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bar':['A','B','C','A','B','C'],'baz':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'zoo':['x','y','z','q','w','t']}, index = ['001','003','005','007','008','009']) #your original df
full_index = ['001','002','003','004','005','006','007','008','009','010']  
df = df.reindex(full_index)
```

output:

```
     bar  baz  zoo
001    A  1.0    x
002  NaN  NaN  NaN
003    B  2.0    y
004  NaN  NaN  NaN
005    C  3.0    z
006  NaN  NaN  NaN
007    A  4.0    q
008    B  5.0    w
009    C  6.0    t
010  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `reindex`

```
df=df.reindex(completeIndex)
```