# assign new row to large pandas DataFrame causes OOM

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a DataFrame `df` like so:

```
      0 1 2 3 4 5 ... 1154161
1     a b c d e f ... A
2     g h i j k l ... B
3     m n o p q r ... C
...
86405 Q V W X Y Z ... ZY
```

Which is a `86405 rows × 1154161 columns` DataFrame. Notice that the index starts from `1`. I am trying to assign a row with `index=0`:

```
df.loc[0] = 0
```

But I run into error:

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 372. GiB for an array with shape
> (99725281205,) and data type float32

I want it to look like:

```
      0 1 2 3 4 5 ... 1154161
0     0 0 0 0 0 0 ... 0       <--- add this row
1     a b c d e f ... A
2     g h i j k l ... B
3     m n o p q r ... C
...
86405 Q V W X Y Z ... ZY
```

Is there another way to assign without running out of memory? Maybe in chunks (preferably not)?

EDIT: Add DataFrame info as per @hpaulj request.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1154161 entries, 0 to 1154160
Columns: 86405 entries, 1 to 86405
dtypes: float32(86405)
memory usage: 371.5 GB
```

EDIT2: note that the letters in the sample DataFrame are actually numbers (float32) in reality

Comment: have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type

Comment: @AnuragDabas for the link, is there a way to do it temporarily only? (im using linux)

Comment: That is a huge dataframe, ideally so many columns in any data model is discouraged. However, you can try and see, `arr = np.vstack((np.zeros(df.shape[1]),df.to_numpy()))` and then `pd.DataFrame(arr,columns=df.columns)`

Comment: Any attempt to grow the frame requires making a whole new one.  Looks like that request is for the data portion.  Is  (99725281205,) the product of the new dimensions?

Comment: To further the discussion, show the `df.info` and the full error traceback.

Comment: @anky your solution still runs into same memory error.

Comment: @hpaulj added info in question

Comment: So your dataframe is already large, and adding a row requires making a whole new frame, at least temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

1.https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement

```
df.loc[len(df)] = 0
print (df)
```

2.https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

```
df = df.append(pd.Series(0, index=df.columns), ignore_index=True)
```

Source:
[Append an empty row in dataframe using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39998262/append-an-empty-row-in-dataframe-using-pandas/54329941)

Comment: Your suggestions will run into the same problem.  They all require making a new larger dataframe (and numpy arrays to store that data).