# Python->Data Frame->Expanding the Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

So I have a Data frame like this:

```
Date;   AK; AL ........

12/31/1976;  128,661;    954,940 

3/31/1977;   128,341;    963,555

.........
```

the Data Frame Shape is (156,56)

These are the rolling average, quarterly number for the 53 U.S territories, and I need to duplicate each row of the data frame (from quarterly into monthly).

So it should be like this:

```
12/31/1976  ; 128,661   ; 954,940 ......

1/31/1976    ;     128,661  ; 954,940 

2/31/1976   ; 128,661   ; 954,940  

3/31/1977   ; 128,341   ; 963,555 

4/31/1977   ; 128,341   ; 963,555 

5/31/1977   ; 128,341   ; 963,555

...............
```

So the ending Data Frame would be (156*3, 56) = (468,56).

Here is my shamefully amateurish way of solving the problem:

```
result=[]

for d in range(dfc.shape[0]):
    a=dfc.loc[[d]]
    result.append(a)
    for i in range(2):
        result.append(a)

result2 = pd.concat(result)

result2.to_csv(outputfile)
```

And now I have a list of 474 data frames in result and successfully join them into result2.  But is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

Thank you very much for your time.

Sample Data from input csv

> Date   AK  AL  AR  AZ  CA  CO  CT  DC  DE  FL  GA  HI  IA  ID  IL  IN  KS  KY  LA  MA  MD  ME  MI  MN  MO  MS  MT  NC  ND  NE  NH  NJ  NM  NV  NY  OH  OK  OR  PA  PR  RI  SC  SD  TN  TX  US  UT  VA  VI  VT  WA  WI  WV  WY  US
>
> 12/31/1976 128661  954940  553053  621466  7130131 808768  1194789 350566  213905  2615803 1462638 326404  848553  234033  3803577 1683495 651434  879378  1101983 1942755 1133973 299863  2999407 1425506 1472189 563727  219449  1736735 158068  454897  272603  2247374 284290  233236  5677756 3768974 757678  803867  3796384 456596  326356  836472  166527  1279266 3905285 68009341    362019  1449598  -      136259  1052788 1626165 481509  118196  136018680
>
> 3/31/1977  128341  963555  559382  632022  7210477 818252  1203495 349061  212093  2637798 1478518 329504  859381  237540  3829280 1700039 657837  886421  1110438 1950984 1140207 302194  3033862 1444873 1482550 569446  221903  1751718 159539  460068  276727  2254050 288767  239391  5685289 3785281 765835  816312  3807158 457408  329745  842357  168075  1289540 3953044 68563641    367915  1462887  -      137377  1069036 1640823 485301  120550  137127279
>
> 6/30/1977  126396  977083  567917  643876  7305609 829959  1215449 349629  212099  2672554 1495769 332130  869226  241135  3858154 1721593 665523  898318  1122502 1964295 1154737 304645  3069330 1463964 1497019 576081  223573  1772303 161208  464668  278415  2271529 293668  245175  5707264 3815464 774473  829472  3826951 455636  332956  850164  169482  1305168 4003226 69279773    373785  1479718 7696    138750  1087648 1660930 492362  123099  138559545

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [`Resampler.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tseries.resample.Resampler.ffill.html). But there is problem with last values - need manualy add last row with datetime shifted to `2` months and with all same values as last row of original `DataFrame`

```
#convert column to datetime
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

#duplicated last row to another row with same values
df.loc[df.index[-1] + 1] = df.iloc[-1]
#shifted 2 months in column 'Date'
df.loc[df.index[-1], 'Date'] = df.loc[df.index[-1], 'Date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=2)
print (df)
        Date       AK       AL
0 1976-12-31  128,661  954,940
1 1977-03-31  128,341  963,555
2 1977-05-31  128,341  963,555

df = df.set_index('Date').resample('M').ffill()
print (df)
                 AK       AL
Date                        
1976-12-31  128,661  954,940
1977-01-31  128,661  954,940
1977-02-28  128,661  954,940
1977-03-31  128,341  963,555
1977-04-30  128,341  963,555
1977-05-31  128,341  963,555
```

If use old version of pandas need parameter `fill_method='ffill'` instaed `.ffill()` - [see changed API in 0.18.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#resample-api):

```
df = pd.read_csv('quarter to month.csv', thousands=',')
print (df) 
           Date      AK       AL       AR       AZ        CA       CO  \
0    12/31/1976  128661   954940   553053   621466   7130131   808768   
1     3/31/1977  128341   963555   559382   632022   7210477   818252   
2     6/30/1977  126396   977083   567917   643876   7305609   829959   
3     9/30/1977  121677   992007   576480   657475   7403502   844079   
...
...  

df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

df.loc[df.index[-1] + 1] = df.iloc[-1]
#shifted 2 months in column 'Date'
df.loc[df.index[-1],'Date']=df.loc[df.index[-1],'Date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=2)

df = df.set_index('Date').resample('M', fill_method='ffill')
print (df)
               AK       AL       AR       AZ        CA       CO       CT  \
Date                                                                        
1976-12-31  128661   954940   553053   621466   7130131   808768  1194789   
1977-01-31  128661   954940   553053   621466   7130131   808768  1194789   
1977-02-28  128661   954940   553053   621466   7130131   808768  1194789   
1977-03-31  128341   963555   559382   632022   7210477   818252  1203495   
1977-04-30  128341   963555   559382   632022   7210477   818252  1203495   
1977-05-31  128341   963555   559382   632022   7210477   818252  1203495   
1977-06-30  126396   977083   567917   643876   7305609   829959  1215449   
1977-07-31  126396   977083   567917   643876   7305609   829959  1215449   
1977-08-31  126396   977083   567917   643876   7305609   829959  1215449   
1977-09-30  121677   992007   576480   657475   7403502   844079  1227102   
1977-10-31  121677   992007   576480   657475   7403502   844079  1227102   
1977-11-30  121677   992007   576480   657475   7403502   844079  1227102   
1977-12-31  120632  1005809   585722   672041   7543093   863180  1242052   
...
...
```

Explanation:

`Resample` omit last 2 rows, so you need manually add it to `DataFrame` for desired output. First find last index value by `df.index[-1]` (index is monotonic (0,1,2,3..) and there are only integers). Then add `1` and get index of another row - e.g. if last index is `50`, another row index is `51`.
Then expand `Dataframe` by [loc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24888331/2901002) and add same values as last row - I use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for selecting last row.
Then need change values of `Date` column in last row. So select it by `df.loc[df.index[-1], 'Date']` and add two months by [offset](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects) (`IN [87]`). Then you can use `resample` and get many new rows, in last rows get new row between old original last row and new original applying `dateoffset`.

Comment: Try before my code reset index by `df = df.reset_index()`

Comment: When I run your code, I got "DataError: No numeric types to aggregate"

Comment: what is your pandas version? `print (pd.show_versions())` . What is `df.info()` ?

Comment: Can you send me your data by email (from my profile) ?

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution.  I have learned a few new trick for dataframe manipulations. @jezrael

Comment: I looked at your solution and the bulk of your work is in this line:
`df = df.set_index('Date').resample('M').ffill()`

So if you could expand a little bit about the line of code above, and perhaps this line:

`df.loc[df.index[-1],'Date']=df.loc[df.index[-1],'Date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=2)`

for the benefits of those who will read this later, and myself right now as well (I am reading pandas documentation right now to understand your code, and..the migraine!).

Thanks
@jezrael

Comment: sure, give me a sec.