# Python create linear regression prediction pandas dataframe by group

Tags: python, dataframe, linear-regression

I want to create a python pandas dataframe column based on a linear regression loop

This is the source data pandas dataframe df:

```
campaign    |     date     |    shown 
   A           2015-10-11       363563
   A           2015-10-12       345657
   A           2015-10-13       345346
   B           2015-10-11       23467
   B           2015-10-15       357990
   C           2015-10-11       97808
```

I want to user linear regression and for each group predict the amount shown for 2015-11-30.

So this is the final new prediction dataframe I am looking for:

```
 campaign |   Prediction(2015-11-30)
      A           ...
      B           ...
      C           ...
```

my code so far:

```
df['date_ordinal'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.toordinal())
model = LinearRegression()
X = df[['date_ordinal']]
y = df.shown
model.fit(X, y)   

df_results = pd.DataFrame()
for (group, df_gp) in df.groupby('campaign'):
   df_results['campaign'] = group
   X=df_gp[['date_ordinal']]
   y=df_gp.shown
   model.fit(X,y)
   coefs = list(zip(X.columns, model.coef_))
   df_results['prediction'] = model.predict(735947)

df_results
```

However, when I run this code, I only get one prediction, I don't get a dataframe with one column "group" and the predicted values next to it.

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
groups = []
results = []
for (group, df_gp) in df.groupby('campaign'):
    X=df_gp[['date_ordinal']]
    y=df_gp.shown
    model.fit(X,y)
    coefs = list(zip(X.columns, model.coef_))
    results.append(model.predict(735947)[0])
    groups.append(group)

df_results = pd.DataFrame({'campaign':groups, 'prediction':results})
```

According to answers here: [add one row in a pandas.DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe) adding rows one by one is not the most efficient solution. And as you also see in the anwers there is that data must be inserted at an index.