# Getting error when adding a new row to my existing dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have the below data frame.

```
df3=pd.DataFrame(columns=["Devices","months"])
```

I am getting row value from a loop
row,
     print(data)

```
    Devices     months
1  Powerbank  Feb month
```

When I am adding this data row to my df3 I am getting an error.

```
  df3.loc[len(df3)]=data
```

> ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns

Comment: try to use `append`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add one row to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-to-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

use

```
df3 = pd.concat([df3, data], axis=0)
```

or as suggested by @Wen use

```
df3 = df3.append(data)
```

Comment: `axis=0` is a default value and can be omitted

Comment: If you do not use the `ignore_index` then maybe will appear a error. `df3 = df3.append(data, ignore_index=True )`

Answer (score 12):

From https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html:

> It is worth noting however, that concat (and therefore append) makes a full copy of the data, and that constantly reusing this function can create a significant performance hit. If you need to use the operation over several datasets, use a list comprehension.

You should use loc, like you were trying to do, and with a dictionary where the keys are the column names and the values are the data of the row being added.

```
import pandas as pd

df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Devices","months"])
new_entry = {'Devices': 'device1', 'months': 'month1'}

df3.loc[len(df3)] = new_entry
```

Comment: how to append a dataframe to an existing dataframe using the above technique?

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking to append new row which is in dictionary format, below will help.

- Existing DataFrame

> ```
> In [6]: df
> Out[6]: 
>      Devices     months
> 0  Powerbank  Feb month
>
> In [7]:
> ```

- Below snippet adds another row to existing DataFrame.

> ```
> In [7]: dictionary_row = {"Devices":"Laptop","months":"Mar month"}
>
> In [8]: df = df.append(dictionary_row, ignore_index=True)
>
> In [9]: df
> Out[9]: 
>      Devices     months
> 0  Powerbank  Feb month
> 1     Laptop  Mar month
>
> In [10]:
> ```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests the number of columns should of the data being inserted into the `dataframe` must match the number of columns of the `dataframe`

```
>>> df3=pd.DataFrame(columns=["Devices","months"])
>>> df3.loc[len(df3)] = ['Powerbank','Feb']
>>> df3
     Devices months
0  Powerbank    Feb
>>> data = ['powerbank','feb']
>>> df3.loc[len(df3)] = data
>>> df3
     Devices months
0  Powerbank    Feb
1  powerbank    feb
```