# Setting With Enlargement: How to add one row DataFrame to another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create an empty `DataFrame` where I will append others single row `DataFrame` with new data. I am trying to use panda's "[Setting With Enlargement](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement)" for efficient appending.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame(columns=["open","high","low","close","volume","open_interest"])

row_one = DataFrame({"open":10,"high":11,"low":9,"close":10,"volume":100,"open_interest":np.NAN}, index = [datetime(2017,1,1)])
row_two = DataFrame({"open":9,"high":12,"low":8,"close":10.50,"volume":500,"open_interest":np.NAN}, index = [datetime(2017,1,2)])
```

Now, when I try to append the new row following the setting with enlargement rules:

```
df[row_one.index] = row_one.columns
```

I get this error:

```
"DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None) not in index"
```

I thought the row should be automatically added because it is not in the `DataFrame`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use `.loc`: `df.loc[row_one.index]`.

Comment: Are you trying to add a column or a row?

Comment: I am trying to add rows that will always have the same columns but a different datetime as their index

Comment: You'll be better off using `append`, or better yet (if you have all rows available at once) `concat`.

Comment: Best of all would be to avoid re-sizing a dataframe at all. If you are accumulating data in an iterative fashion then dictionaries are much more efficient (speed-wise). When you change the length of a dataframe, I believe it has to re-allocate the entire dataframe in memory (someone correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: This [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47979665/1609514) has some timing results for the various methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for setting by enlargement, then select `index` value by `[0]` for scalar and last 'convert'  `row_one` to Series by selecting via `iloc`:

```
df.loc[row_one.index[0]] = row_one.iloc[0]
print (df)
            open  high  low  close  volume  open_interest
2017-01-01  10.0  11.0  9.0   10.0   100.0            NaN
```

But better is use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), especially if multiple `df`s:

```
df = pd.concat([row_one, row_two])
```

Comment: is concat more efficient than setting with enlargment?

Comment: If have multiple dataframes and need one, better is `concat`.

Comment: I get new data from an event so I only have to add a one row dataframe each time.Using timeit I get: 1000 loops, best of 3: 511 µs per loop for setting with enlargement using loc and 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.29 ms per loop for concat so it seems that setting using loc is actually faster than pd.concat

Comment: `concat` copies the data to a new dataframe whereas setting with enlargement appends to the current dataframe. This is why you see that setting with enlargement is more efficient.

Comment: @MoustafaAAtta - Thank you for comment, I think you are right.

Comment: Please note that setting with enlargement still has to copy some data under the hood. Hence, I would recommend to preallocate a dataframe or buffer the rows to be appended whenever possible. I don't know how setting with enlargement works exactly but my reference was an issue https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10692

Answer (score 0):

Since you say in the comments

> I get new data from an event so I only have to add a one row dataframe each time.

I think you are much better off pre-allocating memory in blocks or using a buffering system (as pointed out by @MoustafaAAtta in the comments).

Do you need the full, updated dataframe each iteration?

If not, do this:

```
new_row_data = {'open': 10.0,
 'high': 11.0,
 'low': 9.0,
 'close': 10.0,
 'volume': 100.0,
 'open_interest': np.nan}
new_row_index = pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00')

index = []
records = []
for _ in range(500):
    index.append(new_row_index)
    records.append(new_row_data)  # add new data here

# Create dataframe at the end
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records, index=index)
```

(Code above takes about 2.4 ms).

If you need the dataframe each iteration:

```
buffer_size = 100  # adjust to your needs
data_columns = ["open","high","low","close","volume","open_interest"]
all_columns = ['DateTime'] + data_columns  # Add column for datetimes
df_empty = pd.DataFrame(None, index=range(buffer_size),
                        columns=all_columns)
# Note: You might want to specify dtypes above rather than np.nans

df = df_empty.copy()
index = 0
for _ in range(500):
    df.loc[index, 'DateTime'] = new_row_index
    df.loc[index, columns] = new_row_data  # add new data here
    # Updated dataframe if you need it:
    #print(df.loc[:index])

    index += 1
    while index >= len(df):
        df = pd.concat([df, df_empty.reindex(range(index, index + buffer_size))])

# To remove the integer index use:
df = df.loc[:index-1].set_index('DateTime', drop=True)
```

(Code above takes about 540 ms).

You will find both of these are much faster overall than using `concat` or `append` each iteration (not what DataFrames were designed for).