# FeedParser, Removing Special Characters and Writing to CSV

Tags: python, csv, feedparser

I'm learning Python. I've set myself a wee goal of building a RSS scraper. I'm trying to gather the Author, Link and Title. From there I want to write to a CSV.

I'm encountering some problems. I've search for the answer since last night but can't seem to find a solution. I do have a feeling that is a bit of knowledge that I'm missing between what feedparser is parsing and moving it to a CSV but I don't have the vocabulary yet to know what to Google.

1. How do I remove special characters such as '[' and '''?
2. How do I a write author, link and title to a new row when I'm creating the new file?

**1 Special Characters**

```
rssurls = 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch/'

techart = feedparser.parse(rssurls)
# feeds = []

# for url in rssurls:
#     feedparser.parse(url)
# for feed in feeds:
#     for post in feed.entries:
#         print(post.title)

# print(feed.entires)

techdeets = [post.author + " , " + post.title + " , " + post.link  for post in techart.entries]
techdeets = [y.strip() for y in techdeets]
techdeets
```

*Output*: I get the information I need but the .strip tag doesn't strip.

> ['Darrell Etherington , Spin launches first city-sanctioned dockless
>   bike sharing in Bay Area ,
>   http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/Techcrunch/~3/BF74UZWBinI/',  'Ryan
>   Lawler , With $5.3 million in funding, CarDash wants to change how you
>   get your car serviced ,
>   http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/Techcrunch/~3/pkamfdPAhhY/',  'Ron
>   Miller , AlienVault plug-in searches for stolen passwords on Dark Web
>   , http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/Techcrunch/~3/VbmdS0ODoSo/',  'Lucas
>   Matney , Firefox for Windows gets native WebVR support, performance
>   bumps in latest update ,
>   http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/Techcrunch/~3/j91jQJm-f2E/',...]

**2) Writing to CSV**

```
import csv

savedfile = open('/test1.txt', 'w')
savedfile.write(str(techdeets) + "/n")
savedfile.close()

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/test1.txt', encoding='cp1252')
df
```

*Output*:
The output was a dataframe with only 1 row and multiple columns.

Comment: You can use a regex to eliminate anything that is not in `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` like so: `re.sub(r'\w', '', string)` where `r'\w'` is the raw string for the (shorthand of) the character range above), `''` is the replacement (in this case, an empty string), and `string` is the arbitrary name for the string you want to operate on.

Comment: `techdeets = [post.author + " , " + post.title + " , " + post.link  for post in techart.entries]` replace with: `techdeets = [','.join([*post]) for post in techart.entries]`

Comment: `savedfile = open('/test1.txt', 'a')` opens the file in **append** mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there :-)

How about using pandas to create a dataframe first then save it, something like this "continuing from your code":

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['author', 'title', 'link'])
for i, post in enumerate(techart.entries):
    df.loc[i] = post.author, post.title, post.link
```

then you can save it:

```
df.to_csv('myfilename.csv', index=False)
```

#### OR

you can also write into the dataframe straight from the feedparser entries:

```
>>> import feedparser
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> rssurls = 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch/'
>>> techart = feedparser.parse(rssurls)
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame()
>>>
>>> df['author'] = [post.author for post in techart.entries]
>>> df['title'] = [post.title for post in techart.entries]
>>> df['link'] = [post.link for post in techart.entries]
```

Comment: I used the first solution and it created the dataframe. It hadn't occurred to use pandas in that way, I didn't even think it was possible. However, there is one problem it's now putting the author, title and link in one column but then replicating that column 3 times

Comment: Second example worked. Would be interested in finding out how to make the for loop work as it seems much more efficient, I think?

Comment: @NickDuddy that's true my bad! I just updated the for loop to get the entries correct :)

Comment: However, in general I think it is not efficient to enter rows one by one. Specially with large dataframe see the comment in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/q/10715965/2839786

Comment: Also I see that pandas strips out all the characters I didn't want!

This works thanks!

Comment: Good to know that :-)