# How to create a DataFrame from custom values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am reading in a text file, on each line there are multiple values. I am parsing them based on requirements using function parse.

```
def parse(line):
    ......
    ......
    return line[0],line[2],line[5]
```

I want to create a dataframe, with each line as a row and the three returened values as columns

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
       df.append(line(parse(line)))
```

When I run the above code, I get all values as a single column. Is it possible to get it in proper tabular format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add one row in a pandas.DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10715965/1278112)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't `.append` to `DataFrame` in a loop, that is very inefficient anyway. Do something like:

```
colnames = ['col1','col2','col3'] # or whatever you want
with open('data.txt') as f:
    df = pd.DataFrame([parse(l) for l in f], columns=colnames)
```

Note, the fundamental problem is that `pd.DataFrame.append` expects *another data-frame*, and it appends the *rows* of that other data-frame. It interpretes a list as a bunch of single rows. So note, if you structure your list to have "rows" it would work as intended. But you shouldn't be using `.append` here anyway:

```
In [6]: df.append([1,2,3])
Out[6]:
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3

In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame()

In [8]: df.append([[1, 2, 3]])
Out[8]:
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
```

Comment: Is there a way to rename column names ?

Comment: @ankitbiradar yes, the easiest way is to pass the names to the constructor using `..., columns=['name1','name2','name3']`

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma rápida de fazer isso (TL;DR):

**Creating the new column:**

```
  `df['com_zeros'] = '0'`
```

**Applying the condition::**

```
for b in df.itertuples():
    df.com_zeros[b.Index] = '0'+str(b.battles) if b.battles<9 else str(b.battles)
```

**Result:**

```
df
     regiment company deaths  battles size com_zeros
0  Nighthawks     1st    kkk        5    l        05
1  Nighthawks     1st     52       42   ll        42
2  Nighthawks     2nd     25        2    l        02
3  Nighthawks     2nd    616        2    m        02
```

**See the example by https://repl.it/JHW6.**

**Obs.:**
The example running on repl.it seems to hang, but that is not the case, the load of pandas on repl.it is always time consuming.

To suppress warnings on jupyter notebook:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Comment: Also, this is definitely *not* *uma forma rápida de fazer isso*. You probably just want `df['com_zeros'] = df.battles.astype(str).str.zfill(2)`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @juanpa.arrilaga,

It seems that you do have a structured file and just need the 1st 3rd and 5th item in the file.

load it and use drop

df = pd.read_csv('file')

df.drop([columns],axis = 1)