# How to write a pandas dataframe into csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I don't get how to do this. I'm trying the follow:

```
OutputData_tmp = pd.DataFrame(columns=('frame_len', 'frame_transport_protocol', 'ip_len', 'ip_ttl', 'ip_src', 'ip_dst', 'src_port', 'dst_port', 'payload_len', 'data_len'))
```

to create an empty dataframe, and then, inside a for loop I do:

```
OutputData_tmp.loc(line)
```

whit 'line' being a list of float values.

Then:

```
OutputData_tmp.to_csv('TrainingSet\\TrainingFeatures.csv')
```

to save the dataframe as csv.

But when I open TrainingFeatures.csv it is empty.. only have the header (columns names)

What???

Comment: Are you positive there is something in your df before you write it?

Comment: This question could use a better [MCVE] (emphasis on Complete). Please show how you are populating the data frame, in a way that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @SuperStew  Yes! The line has something inside xD

Answer (score 0):

You are adding row in a dataframe wrong.

Refer to following link for adding a row.

[add one row in a pandas.DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Rather than doing OutputData_tmp.loc(line), do

OutputData_tmp.loc(i) = line

Hope this helps.