# Inserting rows into pandas dataframe

Tags: dataframe, insert, row

To whom it may concern,

I have the following dataframe and I am trying to insert a blank row at the end of every grouping. Can anyone offer an suggestions? I show my current dataframe and desired output below.

**Current Dataframe**

**Name             Date**

Business1   3/4/2015

Business1   3/5/2015

Business1   3/6/2015

Business1   3/7/2015

Business1   3/10/2015

Business1   3/11/2015

Business2   4/5/2015

Business2   4/6/2015

Business2   4/7/2015

Business2   4/8/2015

Business3   6/1/2015

Business3   6/2/2015

Business3   6/3/2015

Business3   6/4/2015

Business3   6/5/2015

Business3   6/8/2015

**Desired Output**

**Name          Date**

Business1   3/4/2015

Business1   3/5/2015

Business1   3/6/2015

Business1   3/7/2015

Business1   3/10/2015

Business1   3/11/2015

[Inserted Row]

Business2   4/5/2015

Business2   4/6/2015

Business2   4/7/2015

Business2   4/8/2015

[Inserted Row]

Business3   6/1/2015

Business3   6/2/2015

Business3   6/3/2015

Business3   6/4/2015

Business3   6/5/2015

Business3   6/8/2015

[Inserted Row]

Comment: This is likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-to-pandas-dataframe as well.