# Most pythonic way to sum rows in a dataframe based on index groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,'a'],[4,5,6,'a'],[2,4,1,'a'],[2,4,1,'b'],[4,9,6,'b'],[2,4,1,'b']], index=[0,1,2,0,1,2], columns=['aa','bb','cc','cat'])


     aa    bb    cc    cat
0    1      2     3    a
1    4      5     6    a
2    2      4     1    a
0    2      4     1    b
1    4      9     6    b
2    2      4     1    b
```

I need to add rows with the same index.

```
    aa   bb   cc  cat
0   3    6    4    ab
1   8   14   12    ab
2   4    8    2    ab
```

I used the following code:

```
df_ab = df[df['cat'] == 'a'] + df[df['cat'] == 'b']
```

But is this the most pythonic way ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-to-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 5):

Use `groupby` and `agg`

```
df.groupby(df.index).agg({'aa': 'sum',
                          'bb': 'sum',
                          'cc': 'sum',
                          'cat': ''.join})
```

---

Or pass `numeric_only=False` (simpler, but I wouldn't recommend)

```
df.groupby(df.index).sum(numeric_only=False)
```

---

Both output

```
    aa  bb  cc cat
0   3   6   4  ab
1   8  14  12  ab
2   4   8   2  ab
```

Answer (score 3):

We can select the `dtype` of column and determined which type of `agg` function to use

```
df.groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x : x.sum() if x.dtype!='object' else ''.join(x))
Out[271]: 
   aa  bb  cc cat
0   3   6   4  ab
1   8  14  12  ab
2   4   8   2  ab
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one-liner :)

```
(df.reset_index().groupby("index")
 .agg(lambda x:np.sum(x) if x.dtype == "int" else "".join(x))
```