# I have to compare data from each row of a Pandas DataFrame with data from the rest of the rows, is there a way to speed up the computation?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, optimization

Let's say I have a pandas DataFrame (loaded from a csv file) with this structure (the number of var and err columns is not fixed, and it varies from file to file):

```
var_0; var_1; var_2;
32;    9;     41;
47;    22;    41;
15;    12;    32;
3;     4;     4;
10;    9;     41;
43;    21;    45;
32;    14;    32;
51;    20;    40;
```

Let's discard the err_ds_j and the err_mean columns for the sake of this question.
I have to perform an automatic comparison of the values of each row, with the values of the other rows; as an example: I have to compare the first row with the second row, then with the third, then with the fourth, and so on, then I have to take the second row and compare it with the first one, then with the third one, and so on for the rest of the DataFrame.

Going deeper into problem, I want to see if for each couple of rows, all the "var_i" values from one of them are higher or equal than the correspondent values of the other row. If this is satisfied, the row with higher values is called DOMINANT, and I add a row in another DataFrame, with this structure:

```
SET_A; SET_B; DOMINANT_SET
0;     1;     B
...
```

Where SET_A and SET_B values are indices from the csv DataFrame, and DOMINANT_SET tells me which one of the two is the dominant set (or if there's none, it's just assigned as "none").
I found the third column to be useful since it helps me avoiding the comparison of rows I've already compared in the opposite way (e.g.: comparing row 1 with row 0 is useless, since I've already compared 0 and 1 previously).

So, for that csv file, the output produced should be (and actually is, with my code):

```
   SET_A SET_B DOMINANT_SET
1      0     1            B
2      0     2         none
3      0     3            A
4      0     4            A
5      0     5            B
6      0     6         none
7      0     7         none
8      1     2            A
9      1     3            A
10     1     4            A
11     1     5         none
12     1     6            A
13     1     7         none
14     2     3            A
15     2     4         none
16     2     5            B
17     2     6            B
18     2     7            B
19     3     4            B
20     3     5            B
21     3     6            B
22     3     7            B
23     4     5            B
24     4     6         none
25     4     7         none
26     5     6            A
27     5     7         none
28     6     7            B
```

I've already written all of the code for this particular problem, and it works just fine with some test datasets (100 rows sampled from an actual dataset).

Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def couple_already_tested(index1, index2, dataframe):
    return (((dataframe['SET_A'] == index1) & (dataframe['SET_B'] == index2)).any()) | (((dataframe['SET_A'] == index2) & (dataframe['SET_B'] == index1)).any())

def check_dominance(set_a, set_b, index_i, index_j, dataframe):
    length = dataframe.shape[0]
    if np.all(set_a >= set_b):
        print("FOUND DOMINANT CONFIGURATION A > B")
        dataframe.loc[length+1] = [index_i,index_j,'A']
    elif np.all(set_b >= set_a):
        print("FOUND DOMINANT CONFIGURATION B > A")
        dataframe.loc[length+1] = [index_i,index_j,'B']
    else:
        dataframe.loc[length+1] = [index_i,index_j,'none']

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=';')
dom_table_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['SET_A','SET_B','DOMINANT_SET'])
df_length = df.shape[0]
var_num = df.shape[1]-1 

a = None
b = None

for i in range(0, df_length):
    a = df.iloc[i, 0:var_num].values
    for j in range(0, df_length):
        if j == i:
            continue
        b = df.iloc[j, 0:var_num].values
        if couple_already_tested(i,j,dom_table_df):
            print("WARNING: configuration", i, j, "already compared, skipping")
        else:
            print("Comparing configuration at row", i, "with configuration at row", j)
            check_dominance(a, b, i, j, dom_table_df)

print(dom_table_df)
```

The issue is that, being not so proficient in both python and pandas (I've been learning them for about one and a half months), this code is of course terribly slow (for datasets with, like, 1000 to 10000 rows) because I'm using iterations in my algorithm. I know I can use something called vectorization, but reading about it I'm not entirely sure that's good for my use case.

So, how could I speed up the calculations?

Comment: see if `drop_duplicates` is useful for you

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, mohanys, I've edited my question with your suggestions, and I will look into drop_duplicates right now.

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestion and for your time, unfortunately drop_duplicates might not be right for my problem, since my issue is probably in the for loop, which is a nested loop (correct me if I'm wrong, but the complexity should be O(n^2), which is terrible with a 10000 lines dataset).

Comment: Side note: According to the definition, two rows can be dominant with respect to each other at the same time if they are equal, but the algorithm will only yield `A` in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Armali! It is in fact an oversight, but one which does not impact the whole analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another speedup can be accomplished by replacing `.iloc[].values` as well as `.loc[]` with `.values[]`, but with `.loc[]` we have to adjust the subscript, because `.values` takes a zero-based subscript, which is different from our 1-based `dom_table_df.index`.

```
dom_table_df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(1, 1+(df_length**2-df_length)/2).astype('i'),
                            columns=['SET_A', 'SET_B', 'DOMINANT_SET'])
length = 0  # counter of already filled rows
for i in range(0, df_length):
    a = df.values[i, 0:var_num]
    for j in range(i+1, df_length): # we can skip the range from 0 to i
        b = df.values[j, 0:var_num]
        #print("Comparing configuration at row", i, "with configuration at row", j)
        if np.all(a >= b):
            #print("FOUND DOMINANT CONFIGURATION A > B")
            dom_table_df.values[length] = [i, j, 'A']
        elif np.all(b >= a):
            #print("FOUND DOMINANT CONFIGURATION B > A")
            dom_table_df.values[length] = [i, j, 'B']
        else:
            dom_table_df.values[length] = [i, j, 'none']
        length += 1
```

Comment: Ok, this is truly insane, this one, along with the other two suggestions made me run through a 1000 lines dataset in 2 minutes instead of 12 hours. I really don't know how to thank you enough!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a major change of the algorithm, but you can save more than half of the loop cycles as well as the tests for `j == i` and `couple_already_tested` if you choose the range for `j` adequately, so the main loops become:

```
for i in range(0, df_length):
    a = df.iloc[i, 0:var_num].values
    for j in range(i+1, df_length): # we can skip the range from 0 to i
        b = df.iloc[j, 0:var_num].values
        #print("Comparing configuration at row", i, "with configuration at row", j)
        check_dominance(a, b, i, j, dom_table_df)
```

Comment: Whoa! This definitely speeds up the process up to some extent, thanks! I will also try looking for ways to parallelize parts of the loop in order to speed it up some more.

Answer (score 1):

Another (surprisingly) significant speedup can be accomplished by preallocating the output DataFrame rather than appending one row after the other. We can compute the resulting number of rows as

- (*df_length*<sup>2</sup> − *df_length*) ÷ 2

In order to determine the row number where to insert the current output data set, we can maintain a counter now instead of `dataframe.shape[0]`. This gives:

```
dom_table_df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(1, 1+(df_length**2-df_length)/2).astype('i'),
                            columns=['SET_A', 'SET_B', 'DOMINANT_SET'])
length = 0  # counter of already filled rows
for i in range(0, df_length):
    a = df.iloc[i, 0:var_num].values
    for j in range(i+1, df_length): # we can skip the range from 0 to i
        b = df.iloc[j, 0:var_num].values
        #print("Comparing configuration at row", i, "with configuration at row", j)
        length += 1
        if np.all(a >= b):
            #print("FOUND DOMINANT CONFIGURATION A > B")
            dom_table_df.loc[length] = [i, j, 'A']
        elif np.all(b >= a):
            #print("FOUND DOMINANT CONFIGURATION B > A")
            dom_table_df.loc[length] = [i, j, 'B']
        else:
            dom_table_df.loc[length] = [i, j, 'none']
```

Comment: hmmm, why not all 3 answer put to one?

Comment: Because each part is a discrete optimization in its own right.