# append dataframe to add new data to existing column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'am writing a code that requires appending a dataframe to include the new data to a specific column

Here is an extract of the code as below, I'am trying to append dataframe (df), with new data(N) to column name(NAME).

```
Names = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('section-result-title')
    for Name in Names:
       N=Name.text
       df = df.append(N, columns=['Name'])
```

Please advise how to amend the code to produce the required result.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & [provide a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `to_clipboard`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-the-dataframe-with-to-clipboard/52413247#52413247)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add one row to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-to-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Hi- unfortunately it doesnt. I just want to append to a column titled "Name".

Comment: Add just a new column with new values respect the for???

Answer (score -1):

if you want add new column to df, you can try this:

```
name_list = map(lambda name: name.text(), Names)
df['Name'] = name_list
```

you must make sure the length of `name_list` is equal to `df.shape[0]`