# How to split data in a single column into new rows (other columns kept same in new row)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset about gun violence for a project. One of the columns includes the participant types, either victim or subject/suspect. The participant column has multiple values within it for each participant in the incident.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('Gun violence Shortened version.csv')
data.head()
```

Output:

```
 incident_id    date    state   participant_type    
0   461105  1/1/2013    Pennsylvania    0::Victim||1::Victim||2::Victim||3::Victim||4:...   
1   460726  1/1/2013    California  0::Victim||1::Victim||2::Victim||3::Victim||4:...   
2   478855  1/1/2013    Ohio    0::Subject-Suspect||1::Subject-Suspect||2::Vic...   
3   478925  1/5/2013    Colorado    0::Victim||1::Victim||2::Victim||3::Subject-Su...   
4   478959  1/7/2013    North Carolina  0::Victim||1::Victim||2::Victim||3::Subject-Su...
```

I want to take each participant and give them their own row while keeping `incident_id` and date the same:

```
incident_id date    state   participant_type    
0   461105  1/1/2013    Pennsylvania    Victim
1   461105  1/1/2013    Pennsylvania    Victim
2   461105  1/1/2013    Pennsylvania    Victim
3   461105  1/1/2013    Pennsylvania    Subject-Suspect *this was the 4:: instance that was cut off earlier*
```

I'm not sure how to accomplish this. I've seen example of splitting a column into two but not how to take from a column into a row.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. I would also appreciate if you can up-vote it in case it helped you as a compensation of the time I have invested into the answer. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather prepare the data in advance using regular Python's data structures and then create a Pandas `DataFrame` out of it. The reason is that Pandas is not primarily designed for such operations like individual row manipulation and even though there're ways to do it, it's [considered an anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/971141) and it's much slower.

The following piece of code parses the CSV data into a regular list using the [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) from Python's Standard library, while adding multiple rows for each CSV row containing multiple items in the last column. In the last step, Pandas `DataFrame` is simply created from the preprocessed list:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

data = []
with open('Gun violence Shortened versio.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')

    # iterate over all rows in the CSV
    for row in reader:
        # split the content of the last column by the || delimiter into a list
        # if there's no delimiter, it will produce a single-item list
        items = row[3].split('||')

        # append each item from the last column together with other columns
        # as an individual row to the data list, N items will produce N rows
        for item in items:
            data.append([row[0], row[1], row[2], item])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

It's not the final solution, you'll need to skip the first row, clean the individual items from the last column, etc., but that should be trivial.

There are [some benchmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47979665/971141), where the manipulation with rows in Pandas was about 1000× slower than preparing data using Python's data structures and creating a `DatFrame` from them.

Comment: Need to add - item.split(':')[-1] in your solution to clean the unwanted data in there.

Comment: Sure, that's one of the things I mentioned in the last sentence. I want to help to OP, not to write code for him.

Comment: Thank you for this solution it's been very helpful! I've been trying to make some adjustments for multiple columns that I want to do the same thing to(participant_status,participant_age, etc.) how would that work? I tried to write
        items_type = row[3].split('||')
        items_status = row[4].split('||')
        
        items = [items_type,items_status]
but that puts everything into the same column and I want type and status to be their own columns.

Comment: Could you rather update your question and describe what you need there, please? I'm not sure I understand. Ideally, put there example data and how the result should look like. And let me know in a comment when it's done, so I won't miss it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is another script that gets you the output , though solution shared by Dawid looks more faster

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


if __name__ == '__main__':
    df_new = pd.DataFrame()
    pd.set_option('display.width', 100000)
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
    dict = {'col1':[461105,460726]
            ,'col2':['0::Victim||1::Victim||2::Victim||3::Victim||4:Subject-Suspect','0::Victim||1::Victim||2::Victim||3::Victim||4:Subject-Suspect']}
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
    #print(df)
    col1_list=[]
    col2_list = []
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        for rec in row.col2.split('||'):
            col1_list.append(row.col1)
            col2_list.append(rec.split(':')[-1])
    dict_new = {'col1':col1_list,'col2':col2_list}
    df_new= pd.DataFrame(dict_new)
    #df.append(df_new,ignore_index=True)
    print(df_new)
```

Comment: I would rather prepare the data before feeding it into Pandas. Pandas has a different purpose than such manipulations with individual rows. Iteration over rows is [considered an anti-pattern in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/971141).