# How do you export a data set to excel using python? Keep getting the following error "str object has no attribute 'to_excel'"

Tags: python, export-to-excel

I am trying to write a code that will utilize an api to get data from yahoo finance and then export that data to an excel spreadsheet. The code worked fine before I added the last line that's supposed to export to excel. I keep getting the following error message "str object has no attribute 'to_excel'".

```
import yfinance as yf
from pandas import DataFrame

#opens txt document that has stock ticker symbols
fileref = open("a.txt","r")
listOfLines = fileref.readlines()  
listOfLines = map(lambda line: line.strip(), listOfLines) 
fileref.close()


ticker_symbols = listOfLines

#loop over each element and store it in the variable ticker
for ticker in ticker_symbols:
  ticker_query = yf.Ticker(ticker)
  price_to_book = ticker_query.get_info()["priceToBook"]
  industry = ticker_query.get_info()["industry"]
  dividend = ticker_query.get_info()["dividendYield"]
  trailingPe = ticker_query.get_info()["trailingPE"]
  dataset = (ticker + "  : " + str(price_to_book) + " " + str(industry) + " " + str(dividend) + " " + str(trailingPe))
  dataset.to_excel("x.xlsx")
```

Can anyone offer any help?

Ross

Comment: Is there a python library that you're using that will provide an export to excel functionality? I'm not familiar with yfinance, so I'm not sure if that's functionality it proivdes.

Comment: @Jonhasacat the "from pandas import dataframe" supports the export to excel functionality.

Comment: in your code the variable dataset is not a dataframe, it's a string

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the `pandas` module in the above.

In order to export to excel you need to create a `DataFrame` to which you can call the export method. You also need to provide the rows in a `dict` format, as opposed to the current string i.e. `dataset`

Create a list of dictionaries to add, looping through the Yahoo! finance date. Then use this list to create your `DataFrame`. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17496530/9811693) which details exactly how to do this.

You should then be able to use the [`to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) or [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) functions to output the `Dataframe`:

`df.to_excel(path)`