# Passing an array of countries to a function

Tags: python, function, numpy, dataframe, python-holidays

I am fairly new to Python. I am leveraging Python's [holidays](https://pypi.org/project/holidays/#modal-close) package which has public holidays by country. I am looking to write a function that loops over any number of countries and returns a `dataframe` with 3 columns:

`Date, Holiday, Country`

Based on my limited knowledge, I came up with this sort of implementation:

```
import holidays
def getholidayDF(*args):
    holidayDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date','Holiday','Country'])

    for country in args:
        holidayDF.append(sorted(holidays.CountryHoliday(country,years=np.arange(2014,2030,1)).items()))
        holidayDF['Country'] = country
        return holidayDF

holidays = getholidayDF('FRA', 'Norway', 'Finland', 'US', 'Germany', 'UnitedKingdom', 'Sweden')
```

This returns a blank `dataframe`. I am not sure how to proceed!

Comment: You have `return` inside your `for` loop. That immediately breaks out of the function on the the first loop

Comment: Moving return out of for loop gave the same result. :/

Comment: `holidayDF['Country'] = country` keeps reassigning a value to a the same key. Dictionary keys need to be unique. We'll be here a long time of we keep debugging like this; you should take a step back here and learn some python fundamentals

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Appending to a DataFrame isn't great, you should really read the docs. What are you using the DataFrame for?

Comment: ..and many other examples you can find them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-to-pandas-dataframe).

Answer (score 0):

If you change your for-loop as shown below it should be okay for you. Most relevant comments were made by user [roganjosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4799172/roganjosh). O'Reilly, Wrokx, Prentece Hall, Pearson, Packt.. just to name a few publishers... they have some good books for you. Skip the cookbooks for now.

```py
.. code snippet ...

for country in args:
        holidayDF = holidayDF.append(sorted(holidays.CountryHoliday(country,years=np.arange(2014,2030,1)).items()))
 #       holidayDF['Country'] = country  # remove this from the for-loop.
return holidayDF  # move out of the for-loop
```