# Fastest way to append a new row to a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I want to append a row to a pandas data frame without using `df.loc`. I am looking for something similar to the `.append()` method used in lists.

I currently do this, but I'm looking for a different solution:

```py
stupid_table = pd.DataFrame(columns=['max_depth', 'features'])
for max_depth in np.arange(50, 101):
    new_row = pd.DataFrame({'max_depth':[max_depth], 'features':[10]})
    stupid_table = pd.concat([stupid_table, new_row], axis=0)
```

I would like to declare `new_row` as a list or pandas Series rather than a pandas data frame. Is there a way to make the following syntax work?

```py
stupid_table = pd.DataFrame(columns=['max_depth', 'features'])
for max_depth in np.arange(50, 101):
    new_row = [max_depth, 10]
    stupid_table = pd.concat([stupid_table, new_row], axis=0)
```

I specifically want to do this because the real data frame that I want to append new rows to has tons of columns and I am too lazy to write down the new row as a dictionary. I'd rather type the numbers in a list. I do this very often and a more convenient syntax would do wonders for my mental health.

EDIT: I prefer not using `.loc` because my for loop is taking each value in the numpy arrays. Switching the current syntax to `for value in range(len(np.arange(start, stop)))` to make the for loop to use indexes, then I'll have to translate the combinations into numeric values because, in the real example, I have tons of combinations. I'd rather not do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add one row to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-to-pandas-dataframe). The short version is that you can `stupid_table.append([{'max_depth': max_depth, 'features': 10}])`. The longer version is that this is _very inefficient_ and you should probably either (1) use `loc`, despite your preference not to, or (2) build a list of dicts, then convert those to a `pd.DataFrame` at the end.

Comment: [JFYI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Can you explain what that operation is meant to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that is a close as possible to your description is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

stupid_table = pd.DataFrame(columns=['max_depth', 'features'])
for max_depth in np.arange(50, 101):
    new_row = [max_depth, 10]
    new_df = pd.DataFrame({head: [val] for head, val in zip(stupid_table.columns, new_row)})
    stupid_table = pd.concat([stupid_table, new_df], axis=0)
```

However, this is not efficient as the main dataframe object `stupid_table` is being re-assigned inside your main loop. You could ideally save all the new dataframes to append in a new list and do the concatenation in the end. This does not include an index reset for the newly created dataframe, but it might be a good idea to do so.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

stupid_table = pd.DataFrame(columns=['max_depth', 'features'])
data_frames = [stupid_table]
for max_depth in np.arange(50, 101):
    new_row = [max_depth, 10]
    data_frames.append(pd.DataFrame({head: [val] for head, val in zip(stupid_table.columns, new_row)}))
stupid_table = pd.concat(data_frames, axis=0)
```