# Python appending a list of elements to a row of an empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My list has many elements. I want to save them to a newly created dataframe. I want to append each element of this list as a column element to the dataframe.

My code:

```
oplist = [[2,3,4,10,12,3,4],-0.4,1.23456E-6] # list saves all output values
opdf = pd.Dataframe() #creating an empty dataframe
opdf.append(oplist)
```

Present output:

```
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()
```

Expected output:

```
opdf = 
          0                1        2      # unnamed columns
0    [2,3,4,10,12,3,4]   -0.4   1.23456E-6  # first row
```

Comment: Is this what you were looking for? 
`opdf = pd.DataFrame() #creating an empty dataframe`
`opdf.append(pd.Series(oplist), ignore_index=True)`

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? What do you understand from that error message? Repeatedly appending to a DataFrame is unidiomatic and will likely be sluggish, can you provide some more context for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add one row to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-to-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what exactly you are looking for but this gives you the output you have there

```
opdf = pd.DataFrame() #creating an empty dataframe
opdf.append(pd.Series(oplist), ignore_index=True)
```