# How to add one row at time to python datatable frame?

Tags: python, dataframe, append

Given an empty [python datatable](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) frame  `empty_dt = dt.Frame(names= list_features)`.
How can I add (append) one row at a time to it, ([like in pandas dataframe in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-to-pandas-dataframe))

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new 1-row datatable for each row and then append it using `rbind`.

```
for row in datasource:
    r = dt.Frame(row, names=list_features)
    empty_dt.rbind(r)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) .    I find the complete definition of rbind(*frames, force=False, bynames=True) here : https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/frame.html#datatable.Frame.rbind