# Add a row to then bottom of a table

Tags: python

if I have a table of data say 3x3, something like:

```
row1 'blue','red', 20
row2 'green','yellow', 15
row3 'orange', 'purple', 25
```

how would I add a 4th row to the bottom of the table

```
row4 'pink','brown', 30
```

so that now the table is 4 rows and three columns?

Comment: This question is lacking a lot of details. How is your "table of data" implemented?

Comment: Is this a pandas dataframe?
If yes check here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-to-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

with the info you have given i supose you want to do that:

Just create the table

```
Table=[row1,row2,row3]
```

Then append the fourth row

```
Table.append(row4)
```

Then your table will be this:

```
Table=[row1,row2,row3,row4]
```

So if for example you want to take the info from col 1 and row 4 just:

```
print(Table[4,1])
```

Hope it help, have a nice day,

David.