# Add Row to Dataframe With Streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I have a data frame with my stock portfolio. I want to be able to add a stock to my portfolio on streamlit. I have text input in my sidebar where I input the Ticker, etc. When I try to add the Ticker at the end of my dataframe, it does not work.

```
ticker_add = st.sidebar.text_input("Ticker")

df['Ticker'][len(df)+1] = ticker_add
```

The code `[len(df)+1]` does not work. When I try to do `[len(df)-1]`, it works but I want to add it to the end of the dataframe, not replace the last stock. It seems like it can't add a row to the dataframe.

Comment: Does your dataframe have only one column: `Ticker`? Or, do you have other columns as well?

Comment: If your dataframe's length in `N` and you are trying to add a new row to it, that you can do a simple search on stackoverflow for. This problem, in my opinion has nothing to do with streamlit. Streamlit is just getting you the value of `ticker_add`. The next step is adding this to your existing dataframe as a new row (as I interpret from your code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

You MUST first check the type of `ticker_add`.

```py
type(ticker_add)
```

### Adding new row to a dataframe

1. Assuming your `ticker_add` is a dictionary with the column names of the dataframe `df` as the keys, you can do this:

   ```py
   df.append(pd.DataFrame(ticker_add))
   ```
2. Assuming it is a single non-array-like input, you can do this:

   ```py
   # adds a new row for a single column ("Ticker") dataframe
   df = df.append({'Ticker': ticker_add}, ignore_index=True)
   ```

### References

1. [Add one row to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-to-pandas-dataframe)
2. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html