# Generate pandas dataframe based on conditions

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

My sample data is as follows:

```
sample_json = """{
    "P1":[
        {"Question":"Fruit",
        "Choices":["Yes","No"]}
    ],
    "P2":[
        {"Question":"Fruit Name",
        "Choices":["Mango","Apple","Banana"]}
    ],
        "P3":[
        {"Question":"Fruit color",
        "Choices":["Yellow","Red"]}
    ],
    
        "P4":[
        {"Question":"Vegetable",
        "Choices":["Yes","No"]}
    ],
    "P5":[
        {"Question":"Veggie Name",
        "Choices":["Tomato","Potato","Carrots"]}
    ],
        "P6":[
        {"Question":"Veggie Color",
        "Choices":["Red","Yellow","Brown"]}
    ],
        "P7":[
        {"Question":"Enjoy Eating?",
        "Choices":["Yes","No"]}
    ]
}"""
```

I am trying to generate a data frame using pandas as follows:

```
import json, random
import pandas as pd

sample_data = json.loads(sample_json)

colHeaders = []
for k,v in sample_data.items():
    colHeaders.append(v[0]['Question'])

df = pd.DataFrame(columns= colHeaders)

for i in range (10):
    Answers = []
    for k,v in sample_data.items():
        Answers.append(random.choice(v[0]['Choices']))
    df.loc[len(df)] = Answers
```

It creates the df like below

[image]

Although random, I want to populate it based on P1 and P4 on the following conditions:

***(P.S: P1, P2, P3....P7 in sample_json)***

- If `P1.AnswerChoice = No`, fill `Null` to P2 and P3
- If `P4.AnswerChoice = No`, fill `Null` to P5 and P6
- If `P1.AnswerChoice = No` and `P4.AnswerChoice = No`, fill `Null` to p7
- Both `P1.AnswerChoice` and `P4.AnswerChoice` **cannot** be `Yes`

So that it can produce the following data frame:

| Fruit | Fruit Name | Fruit Color | Vegetable | Veggie Name | Veggie Color | Enjoy eating? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| No | Null | Null | Yes | Carrots | Yellow | No |
| No | Null | Null | No | Null | Null | Null |
| Yes | Apple | Yellow | No | Null | Null | Yes |
| Yes | Banana | Yellow | No | Null | Null | No |
| No | Null | Null | Yes | Potato | Yellow | No |
| No | Null | Null | Yes | Tomato | Yellow | Yes |
| Yes | Mango | Red | No | Null | Null | Null |
| No | Null | Null | Yes | Carrots | Yellow | No |
| Yes | Apple | Yellow | No | Null | Null | No |

***Edit**:*

**I would want to handle this with the for loop that iterates over the json to prepare the row for the data frame instead of editing the data frame.**

For example in the following part of the code if it is possible:

```
for i in range (10):
        Answers = []
        for k,v in sample_data.items():
            Answers.append(random.choice(v[0]['Choices']))
        df.loc[len(df)] = Answers
```

Comment: are these Pi referring to columns?

Comment: I am referring to P1, P2, ... P7 from the `sample_json.`

Comment: are you trying to modify the data frame or the json?

Comment: @It_is_Chris I clarified now with the edit. Neither data frame nor json, but preferably the logic which iterates through the json to create the row added to df.

Comment: the way you create the dataframe is inefficient... look at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62734983/8893827

Answer (score -1):

You should not have two columns with the same names in one `pd.DataFrame`. I will just use P1, P2, ... to refer to the columns. You need logical indexing in pandas:

```
# If P1.AnswerChoice = No, fill Null to P2 and P3
df.loc[df['P1']=='No', ['P2', 'P3']] = 'Null'

# P1.AnswerChoice = No and P4.AnswerChoice = No, fill Null to p7
df.loc[(df['P1']=='No')&(df['P4']=='No'), 'P7'] = 'Null'

# Both P1.AnswerChoice and P4.AnswerChoice cannot be Yes
df = df[(df['P1']!='Yes')&(df['P4']!='Yes')]
```

Comment: Thanks. But, can't the logic be added already while adding it to the data frame? I prefer not to edit the data frame

Comment: you cannot do that in the for loop if you do it the way in your code I think. You do not have efficient access to previous elements.