# write the data into particular column CSV python tkinter

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

I am writing the data into the csv file. I want to append the data row by row. How do I achieve that?

```
    # opening the csv file in 'w+' mode
    file = open(filename, 'w+', newline ='')
      
    # writing the data into the file
    with file:         
        writer.writerow(['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'])
        for items in self.data_List:                
            print('items', items)
            writer.writerow([items, self.displayData112, self.displayData])
```

How to append the next data in next row for particular column .

Comment: You can use Panda dataframes to do the same. Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/create-a-pandas-dataframe-by-appending-one-row-at-a-time

Comment: I fixed a missing `' ` after `'Column2`.

Comment: Hi parth, I answered to your question a while ago, please take a look at it.

Comment: it's hard to tell what is the problem here. `self.displayData112, self.displayData` are always the same and you don't want that? how is your data structured? but as is, your code shows no problem

Comment: If you want to append data into existing file, open the file in append mode "a".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### method 1:

First make a header for your `CSV`:

```py
with file:
    # identifying header  
    header = ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames = header)
      
    # writing data row-wise into the csv file
    writer.writeheader()
```

Then add the data you want, under those headers ,using `dictionary`; like this:

```py
    # this part is also in the `with` block.
    for items in self.data_List:                
        print('items', items)
        writer.writerow({'Column1' : items, 'Column2': self.displayData112, 'Column3': self.displayData})
```

---

##### method 2:

Use `pandas` in order to append the `data frame` to an existing file, row wise:
As you said in the comments, that;

> the self.displayData112 has only one row data

Just append the `self.displayData112` once, afterwards append `""` (empty string) to the `Column2`:

```py
import pandas as pd

# make the data you have, as a dictionary
data = {'Column1':[], 'Column2':[], 'Column3':[]}
is_displayData112_added = False
for items in self.data_List:
    data["Column1"].append(items)
    if is_displayData112_added:
        data["Column2"].append("")
    else:
        data["Column2"].append(self.displayData112)
        is_displayData112_added = True
    data["Column3"].append(self.displayData)

# dataframe from dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# append this `df` to the existing `csv` file:  
df.to_csv(filename, mode='a', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: This works for only one time  and every time it create the new csv , I want only one csv file and append the data once it get the newData in  self.data_List

Comment: Hi @parth , I've edited my answer. please take a look.

Comment: Hi @parth , Have you seen my answer? Please give me some feedbacks. Cheers.

Comment: It works as it append the data but issue is that self.displayData112 has only one row data so it printed repeadtedly as much as items are there . If i take that statement out of the loop " data["Column2"].append(self.displayData112)" it gives the error "All arrays must be of the same length"

Comment: Does "Column2" have a relation with other columns or it has independent values in it? @parth

Comment: @parth , I've updated my answer, please take a look at it, and tell me whether it is suitable or not.

Comment: thanks @Behdad Abdollahi Moghadam it works

Comment: You're very welcome  @parth