# Update part of list elements for all key-value pairs in a dict with another dict based on condition

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Say I have a dict where I want to update values daily with today's values, if in the same month, else extend the list for a new month.

```
df_dict = pd.DataFrame({
    'orgnr': np.arange(1,6,1),
    'periode': '2022-05',
    'a':'tull',
    }).to_dict('list')
```

**output**: dict of lists

```
 {'orgnr': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 'periode': ['2022-05', '2022-05', '2022-05', '2022-05', '2022-05'],
 'a': ['tull', 'tull', 'tull', 'tull', 'tull']}
```

And I extend the list if there is a new month:

```
df_newMonth = pd.DataFrame({
    'orgnr': np.arange(1,6,1),
    'periode': '2022-07',
    'a':'new month',
    }).to_dict('list')

for k, v in df_newMonth.items():
        df_dict[k].extend(v)
```

Let's say there is a new day in the new month

```
df_newDay = pd.DataFrame({
    'orgnr': np.arange(1,6,1),
    'periode': '2022-07',
    'a':'new day in new month',
    }).to_dict('list')
```

And now I want to update the recent list values for all key-values where periode is equal to, in this case, '2022-07'

I tried something like this,

```
df_dict.update({k: v for k, v in df_newDay.items() if '2022-07' in df_dict['periode']})
    
df_dict.update({k: v if [num for num in df_dict['periode'] if num == '2022-07'] else v for k, v in df_newDay.items()})
```

**Expected Output:**

```
 {'orgnr': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 'periode': ['2022-05', '2022-05', '2022-05', '2022-05', '2022-05', '2022-07', '2022-07', '2022-07', '2022-07', '2022-07'],
 'a': ['tull', 'tull', 'tull', 'tull', 'tull', 'new day in new month', 'new day in new month', 'new day in new month', 'new day in new month', 'new day in new month' ]}
```

Maybe it's not the best way to store data, in that case can someone point me in another direction?

Thank you!

Comment: why do you use pandas if you convert back to dictionary?

Comment: Because I find it easier to work with a dataframe for other stuff, and according to this I should not grow a dataframe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/create-a-pandas-dataframe-by-appending-one-row-at-a-time

Comment: or for this example, I just found it faster to type it this way, no particular reason