# Referencing previous row in Pandas apply function logic

Tags: python, excel, pandas, array-formulas, cumsum

I am trying to create a clipped cumsum. However, the clipping is based on the value of the previous row.

Below is an example of the data that I am trying to generate.

```
╔══════╦═══════════════════╦═════════════════════╦════════════╦═══════════╦══════════════════╗
║ Idx  ║ datetime          ║ energy_consumption  ║ energy_pv  ║ spare_pv  ║ cumsum_spare_pv  ║
╠══════╬═══════════════════╬═════════════════════╬════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 1    ║ 18/09/2021 04:00  ║ 15.5                ║ 0          ║ -15.5     ║ 42.546           ║
║ 2    ║ 18/09/2021 05:00  ║ 15.2                ║ 0          ║ -15.2     ║ 27.346           ║
║ 3    ║ 18/09/2021 06:00  ║ 15.5                ║ 0.667      ║ -14.833   ║ 12.513           ║
║ 4    ║ 18/09/2021 07:00  ║ 15.1                ║ 5.598      ║ -9.502    ║ 3.011            ║
║ 5    ║ 18/09/2021 08:00  ║ 17.1                ║ 10.638     ║ -6.462    ║ 0                ║
║ 6    ║ 18/09/2021 09:00  ║ 17.4                ║ 15.146     ║ -2.254    ║ 0                ║
║ 7    ║ 18/09/2021 10:00  ║ 17.5                ║ 19.44      ║ 1.94      ║ 1.94             ║
║ 8    ║ 18/09/2021 11:00  ║ 18.1                ║ 23.226     ║ 5.126     ║ 7.066            ║
║ 9    ║ 18/09/2021 12:00  ║ 19.5                ║ 26.246     ║ 6.746     ║ 13.812           ║
║ 10   ║ 18/09/2021 13:00  ║ 20.5                ║ 26.864     ║ 6.364     ║ 20.176           ║
║ 11   ║ 18/09/2021 14:00  ║ 19.6                ║ 24.792     ║ 5.192     ║ 25.368           ║
║ 12   ║ 18/09/2021 15:00  ║ 18.4                ║ 18.869     ║ 0.469     ║ 25.837           ║
║ 13   ║ 18/09/2021 16:00  ║ 18.3                ║ 12.319     ║ -5.981    ║ 19.856           ║
║ 14   ║ 18/09/2021 17:00  ║ 19.4                ║ 4.637      ║ -14.763   ║ 5.093            ║
║ 15   ║ 18/09/2021 18:00  ║ 18.7                ║ 0          ║ -18.7     ║ 0                ║
║ 16   ║ 18/09/2021 19:00  ║ 18.8                ║ 0          ║ -18.8     ║ 0                ║
╚══════╩═══════════════════╩═════════════════════╩════════════╩═══════════╩══════════════════╝
```

I have the energy consumption and PV columns. `spare_pv` is easy to generate using:

```py
df['PV'] - df['energy_consumption']
```

However, I cannot work out how the create the cumsum column. This cannot be done using the `pd.Series.cumsum()`, since logic is required to clip the value if the line above is `0`. I have an excel formula that I am currently using to generate this function. For this example, the columns are:

```
A: Idx, B: datetime, C: energy_consumption, D: energy_pv, E: spare_pv, F: cumsum_spare_pv
```

Row 1 would be initially calculated, then row 2 would have the formula:

```
=IF((E2+F1)<=0, 0, E2+F1)
```

I can do this by creating a list and looping over the DF to append values (similar to the way suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24888331/7891362)), but considering this dataset is hundreds of thousands of lines, this will be very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the cumsum is conditional, I dont think there is a way around looping it.

Instead of using iloc and for this purpose (which is slow) better to do this with numpy instead.

```
D = df['spare_pv'].values

# D = np.random.random(5000000)-0.5

start_value = 42.546+15.5

new_val = start_value+D[0]
D[0] =  new_val if new_val >0 else 0

for i in range(1,len(D)):
    new_val = D[i]+D[i-1]
    D[i] = new_val if new_val >0 else 0
df['cumsum_spare_pv'] = D
```

Ive tried this operation on a random 5 million values as well and it completes in 3 secs or so, so should still be ok.