# how to get time of video during video in opencv

Tags: python, pandas, opencv, timer, motion-detection

I have made a motion detection with cv2 which get video as input and as output it returns a csv file contain the time of the motions that happend during the video. the problem is, I have used `datetime.now()` for the time that the motion happening but the speed of the video is much more faster. I don't have problem with the speed of the video, I don't know how to say the object moved at this time of the video.
It would be great if you could help me :)

here is the  code:

```
def press_it():
            STime=0
            FTime=0
            moji = True
            first_frame = None
            status_list = [None,None]
            times = []
            startTime=datetime.now()
            print(startTime)
            #Dataframe to store the time values during which object detection and movement appears | "C:/Users/mojta/Desktop/videos/pred.mp4"
            df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Start','End','Duration'])
            cam = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
            frames = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
            fps = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
            seconds = round(frames / fps)
            length = int(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
            print(length)
            y=int(values["-IN4-"])
            x=int(values["-IN3-"])
            h= int(values["-IN5-"])
            w= int(values["-IN6-"])


            
            #Iterate through frames and display the window
            while cam.isOpened():

                check, frame = cam.read()
                length-=1
                if moji==True:
                    STime=datetime.now()
                    moji=False

                
                frame = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
                #Status at beginning of the recording is zero as the object is not visisble
                status = 0

                #Converting each frame into gray scale image
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

                #Convert grayscale image to GaussianBlur
                gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21,21), 0)

                #This is used to store the first image/frame of the video
                if first_frame is None or length%500==0:
                    first_frame = gray
                    continue

                #Calculates the difference between the first frame and another frames
                delta_frame = cv2.absdiff(first_frame,gray)

                #Giving a threshold value, such that it will convert the difference value with less than 30 to black
                #If it is greater than 30, then it will convert those pixels to white
                _,thresh_delta = cv2.threshold(delta_frame, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
                thresh_delta = cv2.dilate(thresh_delta, None, iterations=3)

                #Defining the contour area i.e., borders
                cnts,_ = cv2.findContours(thresh_delta.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

                #Removes noises and shadows, i.e., it will keep only that part white, which has area greater than 10000 pixels
                Acuraccy = acuraccySlider
                for cont in cnts:
                    if cv2.contourArea(cont) < Acuraccy:
                        continue
                    #Change in status when the object is being detected
                    status = 1
                    #creates a rectangular box around the object in the frame
                    (x1, y1, w1, h1) = cv2.boundingRect(cont)
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1,y1), (x1+w1,y1+h1), (0,0,255), 3)

                #List of status for every frame
                status_list.append(status)
                status_list = status_list[-2:]

                #Record datetime in a list when change occurs
                if status_list[-1]==1 and status_list[-2]==0:
                    times.append(datetime.now()-startTime)
                    
                if status_list[-1]==0 and status_list[-2]==1:
                    times.append(datetime.now()-startTime)
                    

                #Opening all types of frames/images
                cv2.imshow("Grey Scale",gray)
                cv2.imshow("Delta", delta_frame)
                cv2.imshow("Threshold", thresh_delta)
                cv2.imshow("Colored frame",frame)

                last_frame_num = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
                #Generate a new frame after every 1 millisecond
                key = cv2.waitKey(1)
                #If entered 'q' on keyboard, breaks out of loop, and window gets destroyed
                
                print(length)
                if key == ord('q') or length<=10:
                    if status==1:
                        times.append(datetime.now()-startTime)
                        FTime=datetime.now()
                    break

            #Store time values in a Dataframe

            DURATION=FTime-STime
            FINAL = DURATION/seconds




            for i in range(0,len(times),2):
                if len(times)%2==1 and i==len(times)-1:
                    break
                df = df.append({'Start':times[i],'End':times[i+1],'Duration':(times[i+1]-times[i])}, ignore_index=True)


            #Write the dataframe to a CSV file
            df.to_csv("Times.csv")

            cam.release()

            #Closes all the windows
            cv2.destroyAllWindows
            window.Close()
```

Comment: BTW : Dont' append data directly to `DataFrame`. In this case use `Dataframe` only for output saving as .csv. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17496530/2516697

Answer (score 0):

To calculate `in video time` you have to know video FPS and curent frame number.

```py
        fps = float(self.stream.get(CAP_PROP_FPS))
```

Then try to calculate `in video time` (in seconds) with last frame number :

```py
    videotime_s = last_frame_num/fps
```

Or change it to timedelta if you need

```py
   videotime_td = timedelta(seconds=videotime_s)
```

Now you have relative(to start) video time. If you need absolute time then you can remeber video start time and caluclate each event time

```py
    event_dt = videostartime_dt + videotime_td
```

This method works well for videos with constant framerate. If you have video with dynamic framerate it's more complicated and probably you have to analyze video format(for example h265) and use ffmpeg and more complicated things.