# Appending rows to existing pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe df1

```
    a    b
0   1    2

1   3    4
```

I have another dataframe in the form of a dictionary

```
dictionary = {'2' : [5, 6], '3' : [7, 8]}
```

I want to append the dictionary values as rows in dataframe df1. I am using `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict()` to convert the dictionary into dataframe. The constraint is, when I do it, I cannot provide any value to the 'column' argument for the method from_dict().

So, when I try to concatenate the two dataframes, the pandas adds the contents of the new dataframe as new columns. I do not want that. The final output I want is in the format

```
    a    b
0   1    2

1   3    4

2   5    6

3   7    8
```

Can someone tell me how do I do this in least painful way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a Pandas Dataframe by appending one row at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/create-a-pandas-dataframe-by-appending-one-row-at-a-time)

Comment: @Joooeey `append` is being deprecated in pandas.

Comment: Right, I didn't take a good look at the answers given there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with help of [`pd.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html), setting the columns of `df1` during the conversion:

```
out = pd.concat([df1,
                 pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary, orient='index',
                                        columns=df1.columns)
                 ])
```

Output:

```
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6
3  7  8
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, which uses [`numpy.vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html):

```
pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df.values, np.array(
    list(dictionary.values()))]), columns=df.columns)
```

Output:

```
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6
3  7  8
```