# Transform a list of dictionaries into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I have a list of the form

```
results = [{'Parcel': {'AIN': '2004001003','Longitude': '-118.620668807','Latitude':'34.2202197879'}}, {'Parcel': {'AIN': '2004001004','Longitude': '-118.620668303','Latitude': '34.2200390973'}}]
```

I want to transform this into a dataframe with 3 columns 'AIN','Longitude','Latitude'
I have tried this:

```
appended_data = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0,len(parcel_list)):
    appended_data = pd.concat([appended_data,pd.DataFrame((results[i].values()))])
appended_data
```

This seems to work, but in reality, I have a large list of about >500,000 obs so my approach takes forever. How can I speed this up?

Thank you!

Comment: Using `for v in parcel_list:` might speed things up a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the structure is consistent, it would be enough to unpack each "Parcel" inside a list comprehension

```
pd.DataFrame([result['Parcel'] for result in results])

          AIN       Longitude       Latitude
0  2004001003  -118.620668807  34.2202197879
1  2004001004  -118.620668303  34.2200390973
```

The output of the list comprehension is a list of records of the format

```
[{'AIN': '2004001003',
  'Longitude': '-118.620668807',
  'Latitude': '34.2202197879'},
 {'AIN': '2004001004',
  'Longitude': '-118.620668303',
  'Latitude': '34.2200390973'}]
```

which `pd.DataFrame` can work with.

By the way ... [never grow a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62734983/4909087). Using `pd.concat` in a loop is quadratic space complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension like the below.

```
var = [x.get('Parcel') for x in results]

df= pd.DataFrame(var)
```

Comment: This is essentially using `x['Parcel']` except via a function call instead of native dict accessor syntax :(

Comment: Your are correct. However, I added an alternative method to load dict into data frame

Comment: I'm sceptical about the claim that json_normalize is a faster alternative given its meant to handle very arbitrarily/complex structured json structures, passing it a list of records is using a jackhammer to kill a mosquito. have you timed the two methods and compared execution?

Comment: You are correct indeed. Jason is no way faster. I tested on 2 million rows with 2 columns. Jason is way too slow.