# Having trouble extracting values from a nested list and converting to dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested-lists

I'm trying to create a dataframe with 'team','games','wins','losses' and 'ties.

Here's a snippet of the data:

```
[{'away_games': {'games': 4, 'losses': 2, 'ties': 0, 'wins': 2},
  'conference': 'Mountain West',
  'conference_games': {'games': 8, 'losses': 3, 'ties': 0, 'wins': 5},
  'division': 'Mountain',
  'expected_wins': 9.9,
  'home_games': {'games': 7, 'losses': 1, 'ties': 0, 'wins': 6},
  'team': 'Air Force',
  'total': {'games': 13, 'losses': 3, 'ties': 0, 'wins': 10},
  'year': 2022},
 {'away_games': {'games': 8, 'losses': 6, 'ties': 0, 'wins': 1},
  'conference': 'Mid-American',
  'conference_games': {'games': 9, 'losses': 7, 'ties': 0, 'wins': 1},
  'division': 'East',
  'expected_wins': 1.5,
  'home_games': {'games': 5, 'losses': 4, 'ties': 0, 'wins': 1},
  'team': 'Akron',
  'total': {'games': 13, 'losses': 10, 'ties': 0, 'wins': 2},
  'year': 2022},
```

Here's the code I tried:

```
# Create an empty DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['team', 'games', 'wins', 'losses', 'ties'])

# Loop through each record in the data
for record in data:
    try:
        # Extract the desired values
        team = record['team']
        games = record['total'].get['games']
        wins = record['total'].get['wins']
        losses = record['total'].get['losses']
        ties = record['total'].get['ties']
        
        # Create a new row with the extracted values
        new_row = {'team': team, 'games': games, 'wins': wins, 'losses': losses, 'ties': ties}
        
        # Append the new row to the DataFrame
        df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
    
    except KeyError as e:
        print(f"Skipping record due to missing key: {e}")

# Print the resulting DataFrame
print(df)
```

Im getting an error that the 'TeamRecord' object is not subscriptable.

I'm sure there's a better / easier to way to do this. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: `TeamRecord` is neither in your sample data nor in your code provided. On the line where the error is thrown, what is the code?

Comment: it's referring to the first line under #extract desired values:  team = record['team']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how it's supposed to look:

```py
import pandas as pd

data=[{'away_games': {'games': 4, 'losses': 2, 'ties': 0, 'wins': 2},
  'conference': 'Mountain West',
  'conference_games': {'games': 8, 'losses': 3, 'ties': 0, 'wins': 5},
  'division': 'Mountain',
  'expected_wins': 9.9,
  'home_games': {'games': 7, 'losses': 1, 'ties': 0, 'wins': 6},
  'team': 'Air Force',
  'total': {'games': 13, 'losses': 3, 'ties': 0, 'wins': 10},
  'year': 2022},
 {'away_games': {'games': 8, 'losses': 6, 'ties': 0, 'wins': 1},
  'conference': 'Mid-American',
  'conference_games': {'games': 9, 'losses': 7, 'ties': 0, 'wins': 1},
  'division': 'East',
  'expected_wins': 1.5,
  'home_games': {'games': 5, 'losses': 4, 'ties': 0, 'wins': 1},
  'team': 'Akron',
  'total': {'games': 13, 'losses': 10, 'ties': 0, 'wins': 2},
  'year': 2022}]

rows = []
# Loop through each record in the data
for record in data:
    try:
        # Extract the desired values
        team = record['team']
        games = record['total']['games']
        wins = record['total']['wins']
        losses = record['total']['losses']
        ties = record['total']['ties']

        # Create a new row with the extracted values
        new_row = {'team': team, 'games': games, 'wins': wins, 'losses': losses, 'ties': ties}
        rows.append(new_row)

    except KeyError as e:
        print(f"Skipping record due to missing key: {e}")

# Print the resulting DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['team', 'games', 'wins', 'losses', 'ties'])
print(df)
```

```py
    team    games   wins    losses  ties
0   Air Force   13  10  3   0
1   Akron   13  2   10  0
```

It also looks like your data is borked since the total sum of wins, losses, and ties must result in the total number of games played. That's not the case for `Akron`.

You don't use `get`, see also [Create a Pandas Dataframe by appending one row at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/create-a-pandas-dataframe-by-appending-one-row-at-a-time) regarding `append` which has been deprecated and removed in `Pandas>=2.0.0`. Appending in a loop is in most cases a bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for the input! The data matches the source, so I'll the maintainer know about it - https://collegefootballdata.com/exporter/records?year=2022&team=Akron.   After re-running, I'm still getting the same TypeError: 'TeamRecord' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @WillyTheWalrus_123 Does it solve your problem now? Eh, I didn't see your edit.

Comment: @WillyTheWalrus_123 I've edited the answer, could you try and run the code in a clear Python instance?

Comment: When 'data' is explicitly passed like mentioned above, your code works perfectly. Thanks for that. I updated my full list to be referenced like this, and now it works for the whole thing and I avoid the typeerror message.